# How does Github for Mac synchronize?

Tags: git, github

According to the [Github for Mac blog announcement](https://github.com/blog/878-announcing-github-for-mac),

> Once you're ready to share your commits, or pull in remote commits — just press the Sync Branch button. We'll perform a smarter version of `pull --rebase && push` that reduces merge commits but doesn't rewrite your merges.

What is "a smarter version" of `pull --rebase && push`? What exactly are they doing? Is it possible to do this "smarter" thing on the command line?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The blog post "[Rebasing Merge Commits in Git](http://notes.envato.com/developers/rebasing-merge-commits-in-git/)" (from **[Glen Maddern](https://github.com/geelen)**) illustrates the danger of a `git pull --rebase` **when you have made local merges**:

[image: local merge]

If you do a `git pull --rebase` of `master` on top of `origin/master` now, you would **delete your local merge**.
See the next picture after the rebase: no more merge commit.

[image: no more merge commit]

> This is bad for a whole lot of reasons.
>
> - For one, the feature commits are actually duplicated, when really I only wanted to rebase the merge. If you later merge the feature branch in again, both commits will be in the history of `master`.
> - And `origin/feature`, which supposed to be finished and in `master`, is left dangling.
>     Unlike the awesome history that you get from following a good branching/merging model, you’ve actually got *misleading* history.
>     For example, if someone looks at the branches on `origin`, it’ll appear that `origin/feature` *hasn’t* been merged into master, even though it has! Which can cause all kinds of problems if that person then does a deploy. It’s just bad news all round.

That is what Github for (Mac|Windows) would detect and avoid.

If you didn't detect it in time, the same blog post mentions the following recover:

```
[master] git reset --hard origin/master
HEAD is now at 9f3e34d sneaky extra commit
[master] git merge --no-ff feature
```

Actual Solution:

You can achieve the desired result:

[image: desired result]

> Instead of using `git pull --rebase`, **use a `git fetch origin` and `git rebase -p origin/master`**

I suppose the "smarter version" of `pull --rebase` is that combination of "fetch + rebase preserving the merge".

[Glen](https://github.com/geelen) also proposes the [following aliases](https://gist.github.com/590895) to counter the fact that this sequence of command would no longer use the tracking information associated to a local branch.

```
function git_current_branch() {
  git symbolic-ref HEAD 2> /dev/null | sed -e 's/refs\/heads\///'
}

alias gpthis='git push origin HEAD:$(git_current_branch)'
alias grb='git rebase -p'
alias gup='git fetch origin && grb origin/$(git_current_branch)'
```

[Jason Weathered](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3736/jason-weathered) posted a "http://jasoncodes.com/posts/gup-git-rebase", but now refers to **[git-up](https://github.com/aanand/git-up)**, from [Aanand Prasad](https://github.com/aanand).

Comment: Wow, this is an awesome answer, and it's probably correct. But is there any way to tell for sure whether this is what the desktop Github client is doing?

Comment: @DanFabulich: yes, simply make a merge between one of your local branches and `master`, then click on that "`Sync branch`" (provided your local `master` is behind `origin/master`), and check if your local merge is preserved.

Comment: Works just as you said. Wow, git's defaults are really terrible!

Answer (score 3):

Although @VonC’s answer is pretty darn useful, I wanted to mention of newer [legit](http://www.git-legit.org). Basically what `legit` does is a [smart merge](https://github.com/kennethreitz/legit/blob/dba168103ea2980126c55bea5256e043f7da20dd/legit/scm.py#L124) (much similar, if not equal, to what GitHub for Mac does):

1. Check the log for merge commits with `git log --merges branch..from_branch`
2. And if there’s any, then do the usual `merge`, otherwise do a `rebase`

`git pull --rebase` doesn’t work as per @VonC’s answer, whereas `git rebase --preserve-merges` is kinda better, but creates duplicate commits if you have merged other branches in; so you need to decide at some point if “rebase” is actually makes sense, or should you “merge” instead and that’s what `legit` does precisely (again: just like GitHub for Mac).

Comment: Very interesting! +1 Maybe a good alternative to my (pure git) answer.

Comment: Yea, well… I am sure you could alias `sync` to some bash–foo which does the same basically. You don’t have to go the `legit` path at all. I just wanted to point it out to you guys, that’s all. Cheers!