# Re-basing situations in Git

Tags: git, branching-and-merging, git-rebase

I've read that it's never recommended to re-base a branch which is made publicly available. But let's say I have `master` which everyone is working on and `my_feature` where only I am working on it (but is also pushed to a remote repo). Say I want to merge `my_feature` into master, so I checkout `my_feature` first, do `git rebase master`, then switch to `master` and do `git merge my_feature`.

Is this safe to do since many people have made plenty of commits and are heavily collaborating on the `master` branch (but almost nobody on the `new_feature` branch)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Yes it is safe.
Long answer: Rebasing itself is only dangerously if you do it **wrong**.

**Wrong**:
You rebase a branch (`origin/master`) which was cloned by some people --> bad. In this case you are destroying the common history of 'some' people.

**Right**:
You rebase something *onto* `master`, thats correct.
But you must not forget to fetch the `origin/master` branch from the origin first, and update your `master` branch to it. When your local `master` and `origin/master` branch are the same, you can rebase your changes onto the `master`.

```
git rebase master my_feature
```

Then `push` the changes so that `master` and `origin/master` are the same again.

See: [Git pull.rebase this is a possibly dangerous operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18137918/git-pull-rebase-this-is-a-possibly-dangerous-operation)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's safe because you are only changing history for your local branch by rebasing it on top of master. When you push master back the remote, the history for this publicly shared branch hasn't changed.