# git pull --rebase=preserve loses data

Tags: git, rebase

After merging a branch with `git merge --no-commit --no-ff feature_branch` I made some additional changes, added them, and commited with `git commit`.
So far so good. After that I wanted to push my merge commit but that failed because of no fastforward.

I used `git pull --rebase=preserve` to update my local branch.

The update was successfull but all changes I made were lost! Why does this happen? Is it a bug? I'm using version 1.8.5.

Reflog:

```
5032b06 HEAD@{6}: pull --rebase=preserve: checkout 1454216f11e60ba1de094a2e7deda6e3f1b0eb54: returning to refs/heads/dev
5032b06 HEAD@{7}: pull --rebase=preserve: checkout 1454216f11e60ba1de094a2e7deda6e3f1b0eb54: Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
1454216 HEAD@{8}: pull --rebase=preserve: checkout 1454216f11e60ba1de094a2e7deda6e3f1b0eb54
3c8e15c HEAD@{9}: pull --rebase=preserve: checkout 1454216f11e60ba1de094a2e7deda6e3f1b0eb54: test
1454216 HEAD@{10}: pull --rebase=preserve: checkout 1454216f11e60ba1de094a2e7deda6e3f1b0eb54
467fb1d HEAD@{11}: commit (merge): Merge branch 'moep' into dev
```

At `467fb1d` everything is fine. Then after the pull I'm at `5032b06` with all modifications added to the merge commit being lost! This can't be right.

Comment: nothing is lost: watch your reflog (if thats a problem as well)

Comment: Try it yourself. All changes made to the merge commit are not existing.

Answer (score 0):

`--rebase=preserve` passes the `--preserve-merges` option to rebase. Your merge commit is not a clean merge, it is an *evil merge* (it contains changes neither in any of the two parents).

[`git help pull`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#Documentation/git-pull.txt--r):

> When set to preserve (deprecated in favor of merges), rebase with
> the `--preserve-merges` option passed to git rebase so that locally
> created merge commits will not be flattened.

`git rebase` simply does not support replaying evil merges, it will redo the merge (equivalent to calling `git merge`).

That's only one of the reasons why evil merges are generally discouraged.

Corollary: don't amend merge commits!

###### References

- [How rebase result may differ from result of a merge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44546974/how-rebase-result-may-differ-from-result-of-a-merge/44554714)
- [Evil merges in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461909/evil-merges-in-git)
- [Why are evil merges considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33992727/why-are-evil-merges-considered-harmful)
- [How to preserve adjusted merge commits (conflicting and non-conflicting automerge results) with git rebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68209524/how-to-preserve-adjusted-merge-commits-conflicting-and-non-conflicting-automerg)

Especially the last one echos your problem pretty well.