# How to preserve adjusted merge commits (conflicting and non-conflicting automerge results) with git rebase?

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-merge-conflict

I'm using `git rebase -i --rebase-merges <commit>` to change some commit messages, which works fine. But the merge commits I'd like to preserve had changes or conflict solutions; is there an easy way to redo them?

My current work around is the following:

1. in the interactive rebase overview, change `merge -C <commit>` to `merge -c <commit>` to ensure the merge commit is not automatically committed
2. when the merge commit is up, checkout the state of the original merge: `git checkout <commit> -- .` (`-- .` is needed to prevent HEAD being resetted to )
3. review the staging area
4. continue the rebase

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is git-rerere and how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49500943/what-is-git-rerere-and-how-does-it-work)

Comment: Uh, didn't know `git-rerere` until now! Thanks, it will for sure help me in some other situation. In my current situation, I've non-conflicting but adjusted merge commits, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Royal Road here: when you've made an [evil merge](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461909/1256452) and ask Git to re-perform that merge (with `git rebase -r` or similar), Git simply won't make an evil merge.

For this reason, it's sometimes better to make a non-evil merge and follow it up with a fixup commit, even if the non-evil merge is "bad" in some sense (e.g., does not compile or contains a known bug).  If you dislike that method, sometimes you can make a commit *before* making the merge, so that the resulting non-evil merge is good.  But this may push the "badness" into *that* commit (the pre-merge fixup), leaving you with the same bad-tasting setup.

You have your pick of bad solutions: make an evil merge and avoid rebasing it; make an evil merge and put extra effort in when rebasing it; or avoid the evil merge by using fixup commits.