# Why does a conflict occur for only one commit instead of two in my rebase operation?

Tags: git, rebase, merge-conflict-resolution

I have `rep1` repository with two commits on `master` branch. These commits have `file.txt` with the following content:

```
line1
line2
```

I clone `rep1` into `rep2` and checkout remote branch as tracking:

```
git checkout --track rep1/master
```

Then in this repository I modify first line of `file.txt` to be:

```
line1-modified-rep2
line2
```

Make commit. Then modify its second line to be

```
line1-modified-rep2
line2-modified-rep2
```

Make commit. So, here in the `rep2` I have added two commits to `master` branch that tracks remote `rep1/master` branch.

Now I'm going to generate a conflict. On the remote `rep1` repository I create third commit (there are already two there) modifying `file.txt` on the first and second lines to be:

```
line1-modified-rep1
line2-modified-rep1
```

Ok, now we're all set for merge conflict. I push commits from `rep2` to `rep1`, get rejected and when prompt for `rebase` select this option.

Now, I was reading that `rebase` would apply my two commits from `rep2` (where I modified two lines with prefix `-rep2`) on top of the synced down third commit from `rep1` (with modified lines with prefix `-rep1`) and so I'm expecting two merge conflicts:

1. when first commit from `rep2` would be applied and the lines `line1-modified-rep1 vs line1-modified-rep2` will get conflicted
2. when first commit from `rep2` would be applied and the lines `line2-modified-rep1 vs line2-modified-rep2` will get conflicted

But there is only one merge conflict and upon its resolution I can successfully push my commits to the `rep1`. What am I missing here?

PS. Sorry for the lengthy elaboration, I tried to lay out my case as clear as possible.

**EDIT:**

So the setup before rebase is the following:

```
A--D (rep1)
 \
  B--C (rep2)
```

Added screenshots of the resolution process:
[image]

[image]

So the resulting file after the conflict resolution contains these lines:

```
line1-modified-rep2
line2
```

This is a log of git commands recorded by phpstorm (origin is `rep1` here):

```
23:19:49.586: git -c core.quotepath=false fetch origin --progress --prune
remote: Counting objects: 5, done.[K
remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)[K
From E:/rep1
   acc72ac..e6317e8  master     -> origin/master
23:20:39.118: cd E:\rep2
23:20:39.118: git -c core.quotepath=false rebase origin/master
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: rep2-commit 2
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
M   file.txt
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
Auto-merging file.txt
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in file.txt
Failed to merge in the changes.
Patch failed at 0001 rep2-commit 2
The copy of the patch that failed is found in:
   e:/rep2/.git/rebase-apply/patch
When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git rebase --skip" instead.
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing, run "git rebase --abort".
23:24:33.418: cd E:\rep2
23:24:33.418: git -c core.quotepath=false add --ignore-errors -- file.txt
23:24:33.630: cd E:\rep2
23:24:33.630: git -c core.quotepath=false rebase --continue
Applying: rep2-commit 2
Applying: rep2-commit 3
```

Comment: Tell us more about *how* you resolve the conflict: what does `file.txt` contain after conflict resolution? The answer to your question hinges on this piece of information.

Comment: Another thing: after modifying `file.txt` in `rep1` (by appending -`-modified-rep1`) to both lines, did you run a `git fetch` in `rep2`?

Comment: @Jubobs, yes, it seems so. I've update VCS log commands in my question, and there is the following there `git -c core.quotepath=false fetch origin --progress --prune`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### TL;DR

Only one conflict occurs at the beginning of the rebase operation. Because of the way you resolve that conflict, the second patch applies cleanly; there is no cause for additional conflicts.

### More details

For completeness, here is how to recreate a simplified version of your toy example  from the command line; I've shortened the lines in `file.txt` a bit, for convenience:

```sh
mkdir rep1
cd rep1
git init
printf "l1\nl2\n" > file.txt
git add touch.txt
git commit -m "initial commit"

cd ..
git clone rep1 rep2
git remote rename origin rep1 # for clarity
cd rep2
sed -i '.txt' 's/l1/l1rep2/' file.txt
git commit -am "append 'rep2' to first line"
sed -i '.txt' 's/l2/l2rep2/' file.txt
git commit -am "append 'rep2' to second line"

cd ../rep1
sed -i '.txt' 's/$/rep1/' file.txt
git commit -am "append 'rep1' to both lines"

cd ../rep2
git fetch
```

After all those commands, your `rep2` repo looks as follows (the contents of `file.txt` is shown underneath each commit):

[image]

Now, in `rep2`, you run

```sh
git rebase rep1/master
```

To understand what happens during this rebase, remember that a rebase is little more than a series of cherry-pick operations, followed by some branch shuffling; this is well explained in the [*Think like a Git* tutorial](http://think-like-a-git.net/sections/rebase-from-the-ground-up.html).

First, Git attempts to replay the "`A`->`B` patch" on top of commit `D`. However, Git cannot apply this patch cleanly; roughly speaking, Git, on its own, has no way of figuring out which versions of the two lines it's supposed to keep:

[image]

Not knowing what to do, Git asks you to resolve the conflict, which you do by replacing the contents of `file.txt` by

```
l1-rep2
l2
```

(which is controversial, because that creates an [*evil merge*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27683077/how-do-you-detect-an-evil-merge-in-git), as pointed out by Daniel Böhmer in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27930402/why-does-a-conflict-occur-for-only-one-commit-instead-of-two-in-my-rebase-operat?noredirect=1#comment44284668_27944468)). You then stage and commit the changes:

```sh
git commit -am "conflict resolution"
```

[image]

You now run `git rebase --continue`, and Git then attempts to replay the "`B`->`C` patch" on top of commit `E`... and *succeeds*! That patch applies cleanly; because the contents of `file.txt` in commits `B` and `E` are identical, there is no cause for any conflict here, and you end up with

[image]

Comment: I was just about to give a similar answer but I want to emphasize: The conflict "resolution" given in the question seems wrong (when real content is assumed). It silently resets the 2nd line to the original content but should leave it alone. Whenever conflicts are resolved the result should include changes from both parents where applicable.

Comment: @DanielBöhmer Agreed; that conflict resolution definitely creates when one of those "evil merges". I'll add a note to my answer.

Comment: @Jubobs, thanks for your elaborate answer and for mentioning `think-like-a-git` link and `evil merge`

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your screenshots, you didn't get the conflict on your second commit applied. Check Changes->Log of your PhpStorm and you should see two commits on top of `remote/master`. Or maybe even three, judging from the output of your git

```
Applying: rep2-commit 2
Applying: rep2-commit 3
```

*Edit*

The reason you didn't get conflict the second time is that you have merged it so that the file is exactly in the state of `rep2-commit 2`. If you chose to take rep1 changes, you would have conflicts all the way further.

Answer (score 1):

My two cents.
Just before launching the rebase, you had something like:

`A--B--C--D--E     rep2` 

       `\`

        `F rep1`

After the rebase, you get

`A--B--C` 

       `\`

        `F--D'--E' rep2`

Right?

From the [git rebase documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase), my understanding is that the content of commits D and E are first saved in a temporary area. Commit D is first applied on top of commit F, generating a conflict. At the end of the conflict resolution, commit D' is created. Then  commit E is applied on top of commit D'.  Commit E is the modification of line 2 on file.txt following commit D.  So my point is : conflict resolution to generate D' is the critical step. Based on the choice made, the content file.txt for commit D' is equal to the content of file.txt in commit D. In that case, there would not be any conflict when trying to generate E' on top of commit D.

Comment: thanks, but the setup is a bit different before rebase, see my update about setup

Comment: @Maximus : OK. A and B were just there for "decoration" purpose. What matters is what is going on from C, D,E and F. If you remove A and B from my sketch and 'translate'  my C into your A, you get the same sketch. Anyway, Jubobs has perfectly explained what I was trying to say.