# Why git auto-resolved this conflict?

Tags: git, version-control, merge

Steps to reproduce the situation
1. Create file test.txt in your git master with content

```
A
B
C
```

and commit it.

2. Create new branch test-v1
3. In master branch remove line B, so you have just

   ```
   A
   C
   ```
4. Cherry-pick commit from step 3 to test-v1
5. Checkout branch test-v1 and add B line again and commit

   ```
   A
   B
   C
   ```
6. Checkout master branch
7. git merge test-v1

What I expected to get:

```
    A
    B
    C
```

What I got:

```
    A
    C
```

Question: Why is B auto-resolved and not marked as merge conflict when merging?

I tried different merge strategies (git merge --strategy), but I did not find any where I would get the expected result. The only way was to git rebase test-v1 on master. But I suppose in more complicated setup, it could rewrite history of master, right?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27930402/why-does-a-conflict-occur-for-only-one-commit-instead-of-two-in-my-rebase-operat/27944468

Comment: What is related exactly?

Comment: The question I link to also asks why a conflict did not occur.

Answer (score 2):

As we already discussed in the git IRC and with big help of thiago, which is a registered user on Freenode and a experienced git user, I'll take his answer and put it here for completeness:

At the point you branched off 'test-v1' the file test.txt does have the content

```
A
B
C
```

in both branches, `master` and `test-v1`.

Now you are applying changes in `master` to test.txt and cherry-pick them to branch `test-v1`. After that you checked out `test-v1` and added the `B` back to the file.
 What will happen now when you merge? Imagine I am git now:

1. Ok let me look up the common ancestor: Ahh ok I got it, file test looks like  A B C
2. Lets look for the changes made in `test-v1`: Hmm ok looks equal to the common ancestor
3. Lets look for the changes made in `master`: Ahh ok, something changed, lets take the modifaction into account

-> Result

```
A
C
```