# What do two plus signs in a git diff mean?

Tags: git

I am doing a `git diff` and for the first time, I am seeing double plus-signs next to lines.

```
++        if ($field_name == $selected) {
++
++        echo "field_type: {$field['type']}\n";
++        echo "field_name: {$field_name}\n";
++
++        foreach ( $node->$field_name as $language => $value ) {
```

What does it mean? I googled it, and [this result](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Meaning-of-double-and-in-Gitk-s-diff-pane-td6193433.html) doesn't really explain it. I looked at `man` and the one example I found doesn't seem to explain it either:

```
3. It is followed by two-line from-file/to-file header

               --- a/file
               +++ b/file

           Similar to two-line header for traditional unified diff format, /dev/null is used to signal created or deleted files.
```

What does it mean? I've made changes to the file that are greater than 50% of the previous version. Does it have to do with a file re-write? That's what happened when I committed it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

These lines are added since the last version.

From the manual page:

```
- static void describe(char *arg)
 -static void describe(struct commit *cmit, int last_one)
++static void describe(char *arg, int last_one)
```

> In the above example output, the function signature was changed from
>   both files (hence two - removals from both file1 and file2, plus ++ to
>   mean one line that was added does not appear in either file1 nor
>   file2). Also eight other lines are the same from file1 but do not
>   appear in file2 (hence prefixed with {plus}).

See diff manual:

https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/v1.7.3/git-diff.html

Answer (score 11):

The `++` in diff output is from a ["combined diff"](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#_combined_diff_format), which is the default format for `git diff` when showing merges (or when using the `-c`, `-cc` or `-m` options)

When viewing a *combined* diff, if the two files you're comparing have a line that's *different* from what they were merged into, you will see the `++` to represent:

> one line that was added does not appear in either file1 or file2