# Double plus sign for the last line in git-diff of merge

Tags: git, merge, git-diff

Simple conflict situation during git merge.
E.g.:

```
index e910fdc,492c972..0000000
@@@ -1,10 -1,5 +1,18 @@@
++<<<<<<< HEAD
 +1
 +2
 +a
 +4
 +5
 +6
 +b
 +8
 +9
- newnewnew
++newnewnew
++=======
+ aa
+ aa
+ cc
+ aa
 -aa
++aa
++>>>>>>> br2
```

This is diff for not staged both modified file. I'm interested why at the end of each branch block we have lines like:

```
 +8
 +9
- newnewnew
++newnewnew
```

but not just

```
 +8
 +9
 +newnewnew
```

Thanks.

Comment: Would http://stackoverflow.com/q/29774466/6309 help?

Comment: @VonC I'm afraid no. I nearly understand ++ meaning. But it seems to me that `- line, ++line` is the same as just simple ` +line`

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR**

a merge conflict needs to ask the user to judge which side should do what.

It seems the double plus sign line signifies the end of a problematic section - since it is a line BOTH sides of a merge conflict agree should be added into the final merge product.

**Long Version**

Amazing, I couldn't find any valuable documentation either, but it seems like this is a syntax meant for merge-conflict diff display - at least this is the only location where i've seen this happen.

I think it is based upon git diff syntax, and i will explain:
when git performs a merge, it attempts to merge file A into file B. if there is a conflict, since git wants the user to do minimal work, it creates a partial-merge (work-in-progress) file C, and then asks the user to finish the merge by putting A and B on both sides, and letting the user decide how C should look in the end.

in this case, it means there are 3 files being diffed, and a syntax is required per line to show the relationship between all 3. so no we have more than 2 states for a line, depending on whether the merge decided to enter it into the merge (C) file.

a double plus just means that the line exists in both A and B, but is not in C currently, this is a good hint that it SHOULD be in C, but the merger for some reason couldn't make a choice to add it.

so the minus and plus on both 2 first columns of the diff just means whether the line is missing, existant, or added in the right or left files A and B.

here is a basic example:

A:

```
my original line 1.

my original line 2.

a unique A line.

a new code line
```

B:

```
my original line 1.

my original line 2.

a unique B line.

a new code line
```

C (the partial-diff):

```
my original line 1.

my original line 2.

a new code line
```

lets say A is merged into B to create the partial diff C.

The unified diff window will show something like this:

(replace 0 by a regular space: when its neither minus nor plus)

```
00my original line 1.

00my original line 2.

+0a unique A line.

0+a unique B line.

++a new code line
```

As you can see, the line that is in both files on both sides of the merge is marked as double plus - to say "both sides agree this should be added" while the other ones say "each wants a different part to be added inside" - and this is the hint to the section on which the merge actually failed.

Hope i helped a bit, sorry for the messy look, im not good at using the syntax yet..

Comment: Here's a link to the docs, FYI: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#_combined_diff_format — see the part that reads "A `-` character in column N means..."