# Export a condensed file by file diff/patch between 2 git commits?

Tags: git, diff

I came across this code to export a patch from a specific location in a repository

```
git log --author=jdoe oldbranch..newbranch -p -- path/to/subdirectory > myChangesInSubdirectory.patch
```

It, of course, goes by commit rather than all scrunched together, because that's what a patch does. But I would like to be able to say basically "Here are the files in a particular folder that changed between `commit a` and `commit b` and what changed in them" without having multiple changes to the same file.

I could manually create a new repo out of the original tag and then copy over the other branch and make it one commit that way, but I am trying to find a one line CLI way to output it.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking for.  Could you give an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do that, depending on the precise results you want.

If you want the difference between two specific, already-existing commits (perhaps constrained to specific files / directories as well), `git diff` will do it:

```
git diff rev1 rev2
```

or:

```
git diff rev1 rev2 -- path1 path2 ... pathN
```

---

If you want changes whose commits were within a specific date range, excluding changes outside of that range, it's a bit more complex.  For instance, consider the following graph fragment:

```
... - D - E - F - G - J - K ...
            \       /
              H - I
```

Suppose further that the date on commit `D` is "last Wednesday", but the date on commit `E` is "two months ago", because commit `E` was forward-ported (rebased or similar) from something done much earlier.  Meanwhile commits `F` and `G` are recent, as is `H`, but `I` is also forward-ported from earlier like `E`, and `J` and `K` are also recent, but you decide that `K` is *too* recent.  The commits you want are therefore `D` but not `E`; `F` and `G`; and `H` but not `I`.

In this case, to get all those changes (and no others) as a single patch, you will need to make a new branch starting just before `D` into which you cherry-pick (or equivalent) each of those commits.  You can cherry-pick them individually, then use `git diff` to generate a patch from "just before `D`" to "final result".  In this case there is still a one-line(ish) way to do it since you're not picking up any merges:

```
git checkout -b deliver D^ && git cherry-pick \
    $(git rev-list --since=... --until=...) && \
git diff D^ HEAD [-- paths]
```

Here, we use `git rev-list` to pick the desired commits and feed the resulting SHA-1s to `git cherry-pick`, which adds them on the new branch (`deliver`) created starting from commit `D^`.  Assuming all goes well—not necessarily a good assumption—the final `git diff` compares `D^`, our starting point, with `HEAD`, the result after all the cherry-picking.

(This can be simplified, if you call it simplification at least :-) , by creating the `deliver` branch *after* commit `D` since we plan to include it.  I assume, however, that the `--since` and `--until` values are how you decided which commits to include in the first place, so I think it's a bit clearer this way.)

This all falls apart if you plan to include the merge-commit `J` here: merge commits can be an "evil merge" (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461909/evil-merges-in-git) and [here](http://git-blame.blogspot.com/2013/04/where-do-evil-merges-come-from.html) for details), and these cannot be simply cherry-picked.  So if you *do* have some fancy requirements that require running `git rev-list` to choose commits to include, check carefully.  (Note that you can automate finding merges with `--merges`.)

Comment: Thank you for all that detail! I realize I was unintentionally vague in my question.. but essentially changing 'log' to 'diff' in the original snippet I had gave me exactly what I needed

Comment: Ah.  In that case, you should know that `git diff br1..br2` really "means" `git diff br1 br2` (and adding `--author` has no effect at all).  `git log` feeds arguments to `git rev-list` and uses the entire resulting list of revisions, while `git diff` is special-cased.