# Merge conflicts but no rebase conflicts

Tags: git

So I have branch master and RC branches. When I made a pull request from master to RC, it showed a lot of conflicts. I tried rebasing on RC first (locally) and no rebase conflicts showed.

When I tried merging locally, I also got conflicts. Why is that the case? What can make rebase works with no conflicts but not merge?

Comment: Do you have rerere enabled (`git config --get rerere.enabled`) ? This can be one reason why a conflict can be solved automatically in one case, and not in the other.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most likely reason would be that a commit has been cherry-picked from one branch involved in the merge to the other.  If rebase detects that a commit it's about to rewrite applies the same textual changes as a commit already included in the new base, then it skips that commit.  (There's probably something inexact about that explanation, but it's roughly right...)

So if you have

```
x -- A -- B -- C <--(master)
 \
  D -- A' -- E <--(branch)
```

where `A'` makes the same changes to `D` that `A` made to `x` (perhaps it was cherry-picked, or rebased, or squash merged...), then

```
git rebase branch master
```

would rewrite `D` and `E`, skipping `A'`.  But

```
git checkout master
git merge branch
```

would not look at the individual commits, so you could get conflicts due to the changes in `A'`.

Comment: See also my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/q/44546974/1256452 (includes this case, and two others)