# Why Do I See No Output With Git Log But I Do See This With Git Diff?

Tags: git

Team,

I type: `git log branchA..branchB -- /dir1/dir2`

When typing this "git log" command nothing is output. However, when I type this "git diff" command many files are output.

`git diff branchA..branchB -- /dir1/dir2`

Does anyone know why there is this extreme difference? I have read the documentation but this does not give me an obvious answer unfortunately and i have to venture onto the open seas of the Internet.

Seems like if there is output with the "git diff" command then this means files were changed between the branches (branchA and branchB). If there are changes between these branches as evidenced by the "git diff" command then there should be something, anything, in the "git log" command.

Why does the "git log" command not return anything but the "git diff" command does return a lot of output on file and code changes?

Comment: One possibility: `branchA` is actually _ahead_ of `branchB`. `git diff` will then show the "reverse" diff. `git log` will not show anything, because there are no commits in `branchB` that are not in `branchA`.

Comment: E.g.: `git checkout master; >file echo 'first'; git commit -m '1' file; git checkout -b branch; >file echo 'second'; git commit -m '2' file;`, then: `git log branch..master -- file` (empty), `git diff branch..master -- file` ("-second +first")

Answer (score 3):

#### TL;DR

First, check whether there are any commits in the `branchA..branchB` range, using `git rev-list` for instance (add `--count` if you don't want to see the raw hash IDs).  Then, if there *are* commits, consider adding `--full-history` and maybe `-m` to your `git log` command.

#### Long

There is a lot to unpack here.  (There might be a lot less if you pointed to a *specific* repository and two *specific branch names* within that one specific repository.)

First, `git log` and `git diff` are pretty different beasts.  But it is worth noting that `git log` can *run* `git diff`, more or less; `git diff` cannot run `git log`.  Nonetheless, `git diff` can do things `git log` can't do.  Second, the two-dot notation *has multiple different meanings*.  What it means to `git log` is very different from what it means to `git diff`.  In one sense, it doesn't mean anything at all to `git diff` as you can always replace:

```
git diff X..Y
```

with:

```
git diff X Y
```

That is, the two dots here merely serve to separate `X` from `Y`, which you could also do just by giving them as separate arguments.  That's *not* true for `git log`, though.  That makes `git diff` quite a bit simpler, so let's start with the `git diff`.

#### Diffing two commits

You have run (in effect anyway):

```
git diff branchA branchB -- /file1/file2
```

This form of `git diff`, given two commit-specifiers and a path,<sup>1</sup> has the effect of checking out each of the two specific commits and comparing them.  Without the path limiter, you'd get complete instructions on what set of operations would change the first commit into the second one: add files A and B, delete files C and D, modify files E through H, etc.  Using the path specifier `/file1/file2`<sup>2</sup> eliminates from the output any instructions that affect files whose name does not start with (or equal) this string.  (The leading slash here is just relative to the top level of your repository.)

---

<sup>1</sup>Some Git commands take *pathspec* arguments.  The `git log` and `git diff` commands do not.  If you don't use complicated stuff, there's nothing to worry about here.  If you start using `:/:` or `:(glob)` and other tricky pathspec options, just note that they're not available here.

<sup>2</sup>Note that your OS probably demands that `file1/file2` name either a file named `file2` within a directory / folder `file1`, or a directory / folder named `file2` within one named `file1`.  To Git, these are just strings—there's no "folder-ness" involved.  Still, it's probably better to say `/dir1/dir2` here.

---

#### Using `git log`

There is a lot to know about `git log`; let's start with the two-dot notation.  In this case your two items are `branchA` and `branchB`.  Git will—at least with `git log`, and also with many other commands *but not* `git diff`—first treat this as selecting *all commits reachable from the tip of `branchB`, minus any and all commits reachable from the tip of `branchA`*.  This uses the phrase *reachable from*, which deserves an entire web tutorial: [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/).  (Go read it!)

As [knittl notes in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57733666/why-do-i-see-no-output-with-git-log-but-i-do-see-this-with-git-diff#comment101907918_57733666), this list can be empty, even if the two names designate different commits.  In this case, `git log` will print nothing, as we'll see.  To find the list of hash IDs—without seeing anything else—use `git rev-list`:

```
git rev-list branchA..branchB
```

The `rev-list` command is a major Git work-horse that a lot of Git's commands use, either by running it, or by having it built in to themselves.  For instance, all of `cherry-pick`, `revert`, `rebase`, `log`, `shortlog`, and `push` use `git rev-list` internally.  A `git fetch` also uses it, but runs the `rev-list` command on the *other* Git, rather than on yours.

In any case, `git log` now has, in effect, a list of commits to walk.  It's not at all obvious how many commits are in this list.  If the list had just *one* commit in it, your `git log` and `git diff` would do the same thing—produce the same output—so we may safely assume that the list has either *no* commits in it, or at least two commits in it.  **If it's empty, but the commits are different, your output is already explained.**

If not, things get more complicated, but it's likely that the list of commits has *at least one merge commit in it*.  If we assume that it *does* have at least one merge in it, that also gets us an explanation.  What Git will now do is walk the list of commits, in some order—and **if you hadn't added `-- /file1/file2`** it would now do something simple to explain:

- Find a commit that is to be walked (internally, these actually come off a priority queue, as part of this build-a-list-and-simultaneously-walk-it).

  - Find its parent.  If this commit is a merge, find all parents.  This is really part of the rev-list action: `git log` and `git rev-list` are built from a single source and share most of their code, and rev-list and log both walk the commit graph using this shared walking-code.
  - Print the log message from the commit, plus any leading stuff like the commit hash, based on the `--pretty` format chosen.
  - If the commit is *not* a merge, run `git diff` between the (single) parent and the commit itself, and show that output too.  If the commit *is* a merge, show nothing.
  - Put the parent(s) on the queue of commits to walk, and go back to the top.

So you'd see a `git diff` for every non-merge commit in the list that `git log` / `git rev-list` find by enumerating "commits reachable from `branchB` minus commits reachable from `branchA`".

Now, you would think that adding `-- /file1/file2` would affect each of these diffs so that you see only *those* changed files ... and that's true.  But it does more that that: it turns on **History Simplification**.

With History Simplification turned on, `git log` (and `git rev-list`) deliberately *cut off* parts of the reachability graph.  In particular, at any *merge*, Git goes through an elaborate computation of what the documentation calls TREESAME.  This computation amounts to stripping each commit down to just those files within the list of files and/or directories you specified on the command line, and comparing the contents of each such file.

When one "leg" of a merge is TREESAME on all files, after this stripping of other files, and the other isn't TREESAME, Git *discards the not-TREESAME leg*, including *all* the commits that are reachable through that leg of the merge.  If the merge is an octopus merge, and at least one parent has the TREESAME-after-stripping property, Git picks one at more or less random and follows that one, discarding all the other legs.  (If all legs are different, Git follows all legs.)

Then, since the merge commit *is* a merge commit, `git log`, by default, prints *nothing*.  Even if `git log` weren't skipping diff-listings for this,<sup>3</sup> it has probably just picked some TREESAME parent, so that the diff listing would be empty anyway.  That's what TREESAME implies: after stripping away all the files you *didn't* select, the remaining ones were the same from the merge commit to its chosen parent.

Having chosen the TREESAME parent, Git continues down this track.  If `branchA` identifies some commit that's in the *discarded* leg, you can—I think—now see why the output from this `git log` might be empty: there may well be no changes to the selected files in any commits from here on back to wherever `branchA` rejoins with commits reachable from the tip of `branchB`.

If it is in fact History Simplification that has discarded the interesting commits, adding `--full-history` to your `git log` command will show you the commits you wanted to see.  Of course, it's possible that any changes you were looking for were introduced by an ["evil merge"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461909/1256452), so you might also need the `-m` option, which forces `git log` to show a full diff between a merge commit and each of its parents.

---

<sup>3</sup>You can tell `git log` to print diff listings at merges, using either `-c`, `--cc`, or `-m`, each of which has a different effect.