# What are categories in Diff tab after merge

Tags: git, git-extensions

I made merge of a branch to another branch and there are three categories containing files in the Diff tab:

> Diff with: origin/branch @hash1
>   Diff with: origin/working_branch @hash2
>   Combined Diff

What files are in each category? I merged origin/working_branch to the origin/branch.

Is it like this?

Diff with: origin/branch @hash1 - contains files changed in origin/working_branch
Diff with: origin/working_branch @hash2 - contains files changed in origin/branch
Combined Diff - contains files changed in both branches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of this question is about [Git Extensions](http://gitextensions.github.io/), the graphical user interface.  I have not used that and cannot answer anything about that.  The other part of this question, though, is what these diffs mean / show, and that's basic command-line Git.

Remember, *every* commit in Git holds a full snapshot of all of your files.  For regular (non-merge) commits, it's easy enough to see how this works.  Every commit has a *parent* commit, and hence commits are strung together, one after another, in a line that we can draw:

```
...---F--G--H   <-- master
```

or:

```
* 9fadedd637 (master) a commit message subject
|
* 3bab5d5625 some other commit message subject
|
* 1c56d6f57a this commit does something or other
|
:
```

as shown by `git log --graph` for instance (the above output is simulated and not quite what `--graph` would show, but close enough).

To *view* a commit, we can either check it out, so that we have *all* the files in a work-tree where we can see them; or we can ask Git to *show* the commit by comparing it to its parent.  To see commit `H`, at the tip of `master`, we have Git extract both `G` *and* `H` to a temporary area (in memory) and *compare* them.

Some files in `G` match their counterparts in `H`.  Git says nothing at all about these files.  Some files *don't* match; for those, Git shows us a recipe–a diff listing—by which we could *change* the file in `G` so that it *would* match the copy in `H`.

Merge commits have more than one parent.  When drawing them with newer commits towards the right, as I usually do on StackOverflow, we get something like this:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M--N--...
         \    /
          K--L
```

Commit `M` is a merge, with parents `J` and `L`.

A merge is like any other commit: it holds a full snapshot, not some set of changes.  But we can *view* it *as* changes, by comparing the snapshot in `M` to the snapshot in `J`:

```
git diff <hash-of-J> <hash-of-M>
```

does exactly that, for instance.

We can also view it as changes by comparing `L` vs `M`:

```
git diff <hash-of-L> <hash-of-M>
```

Either diff will show *changes*.  The changes they'll show are different, though.

Since `M` is a merge commit, what we'll see, when looking at `J`-vs-`M`, is the changes we brought in from the work done along the *bottom* row, in commits `K` and `L`.  If we compare `L`-vs-`M`, we'll see the changes we brought in from the work done along the *top* row, in commits `I` and `J`.  Note that it's possible that `L` is a cherry-pick of `I`, for instance, so that the work is duplicated.  In this case, the merge took only *one copy* of these changes, not two copies, so we *won't* see that in *either* of these two diffs.

A *combined diff* is something else entirely.  It is, in my opinion, an attempt to be useful that is not as successful as one might like.  What a Git combined diff does is, first, run each of the individual diffs—in this case, `J` vs `M` and `L` vs `M`—and then *throw out* from this diff any file that's *not* changed at all in the other diff.

That is, suppose that in `H`, we had four files, all of which are also in `I`, `J`, `K`, `L`, and `M`, and these properties hold:

- `same.txt` is the same in all six commits.
- `top-only.txt` gets modified in `I` and/or `J`, but not in `K` and/or `L`.
- `bot-only.txt` gets modified in `K` and/or `L`, but not in `I` and/or `J`.
- `both.txt` gets modified in `J` and also in `L`.

We will also assume that `M` is not an evil merge (see [Evil merges in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461909/1256452)).  That is, `H`-vs-`M`, if we run that diff, will *not* show any changes that were not acquired through `I`, `J`, `K`, or `L`.  Moreover, we'll assume that the changes to `both.txt` did not overlap at all, so that the merge combined both changes: no conflicts, no other issues.

Obviously, diffing `J` vs `M` shows nothing for `same.txt`: it was not touched in any of the five commits that come after `H`.

Diffing `J` vs `M` *does not show* `top-only.txt` because the copy in `M` matches the copy in `J`.  Changes to this file happened in `I` and/or `J`, i.e., comparing `H` with `J` shows changes, but those changes to the `H` version of `top-only.txt`, resulting in the `J` version of the `top-only.txt`, are applied to the `H` version to get the `M` version.

Diffing `L` vs `M` *does not show* `bot-only.txt` for the same reason.  Again, the `M` copy of `bot-only.txt` matches the `L` copy.

Only for `both.txt` are there differences between `J` and `M` *and* differences between `L` and `M`.

If we ask Git for a *combined diff* view of `M`, Git will now:

- diff `J` vs `M`: two files are changed: `top-only.txt` and `both.txt`; and
- diff `L` vs `M`: two files are changed: `bot-only.txt` and `both.txt`.

So the list has three files changed, one in both diffs and one only in one each.  The combined diff now *throws out* the only-in-one-diff files, leaving only the one file `both.txt`.

At this point, you have an option of two different kinds of combined diff:

- `git diff --cc` (the default: note two dashes and two `c`s): this prints *nothing*.
- `git diff -c` (note one dash and one `c`): this shows a diff for `both.txt`.

The `--cc` one actually makes sense.  The idea here is to show you where there was a *merge conflict*.  Since there *wasn't* a merge conflict, it does not show anything.  (For a case where it does show something, see [the combined diff format section of the `git diff` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#_combined_diff_format).)

The `-c` one makes sense too, except for one thing: it doesn't show you `top-only.txt`, nor `bot-only.txt`.  What we really need here, but Git does not have, is a way to compare the *merge result* snapshot with the *merge base* snapshot.  That is, we might like to view `H` vs `M`.  There is no built in operation to do this, despite the fact that I think there probably should be.

The output from `git show -c`, which runs this sort of combined diff, on a test repository I made here, is:

```
commit 54627dbf51ab9b27c8e5486e4755651688dd5d21 (HEAD -> merge)
Merge: da92a96 e77c224
[snip]
diff --combined both.txt
index 5d51eed,506867f..1f3f391
--- a/both.txt
+++ b/both.txt
@@@ -2,10 -2,10 +2,11 @@@ this fil
  will be
  modified in
  both branches.
 +here is the top-branch change

  The changes
  will be
  combined into
  one file
  in the merge result.
+ here is the bottom-branch change
```

We *can* do it manually.  See the script below (named `git-show-merge` so I can run it as `git show-merge`).  This basically finds the merge base from the parents of the specified merge (or `HEAD` as the default), then runs the desired diff.

Git also has the `-m` option, available for `git show` and `git log` both.  This flag effectively "splits" the merge into separate "virtual commits".  Each one is a single-parent commit, whose single parent is one of the parents from the actual merge.  Git's internal difference engine is then good with diff-ing that commit as an ordinary diff, to show you which files it changed.

In this case, then, `git show -m <hash-of-M>` will diff `J`-vs-`M` first, then `L`-vs-`M` second, and show you both diffs.

It looks like Git Extensions does not have the `-m` option but does have the option to show either the `J`-vs-`M` diff, or the `L`-vs-`M` diff, or—if you select it—one of the combined-diff formats, probably the `--cc` variant.

Note that `git log -p` defaults to not even *attempting* to show a merge.  Use an explicit `-c` or `--cc` option to force `git log` to show a combined diff.

---

```sh
#! /bin/sh
USAGE="[commit]  the merge commit to show - default is HEAD"
. git-sh-setup
case $# in
0) set HEAD;;
1) ;;
*) usage;;
esac
commit=$1
hash=$(git rev-parse ${commit}^{commit}) || exit
set -- $(git rev-parse $hash^@)
[ $# -ge 2 ] || die "$commit ($hash) is not a merge"
set -- $(git merge-base --all $@)
case $# in
0) die "parents of ${commit} are unrelated";;
1) ;;
*) echo "warning: more than one merge base, diffing against $1";;
esac
git diff $1 $hash
```