# Git merge just overwrites a branch?

Tags: git, git-merge

I am pretty new to git and I can't get it to merge changes the way I want it to. So here is what I am trying to accomplish:

I need to update our learning management system.
I have 2 branches I am working on: mergebranch and update. On mergebranch, I have the old version of the system that has some custom changes and files that are not in the update, but I need them to be in the updated version as well. Then on the update branch, I have the fresh files from the new version.

I tried `git merge update` which led to git deleting custom files that were in mergebranch, but not in update. Also, there were no merge conflicts which I found really strange. I looked at the version text file which only had the version number in the first line. I expected a conflict, but git just overwrote the old version number with the new one. It seems like git just copies the new version over the old and there is no merging happening. Also I get these "delete mode" and "create mode" messages that I don't understand.

So here is what I did in git:

- cloning the files from the server to a local directory

`git checkout -b update`

- deleting old files and replacing them with the fresh files from the update

```
git add .
git commit -m "Update vanilla version"
git checkout master
git checkout -b mergebranch
git merge update
```

Can anyone help me out? I am lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you can understand `git merge`, you need to understand that Git isn't really about branches or files.  Git is, instead, all about *commits*.  This means you need to know precisely what a commit is and does.  We won't cover everything here, but these are the relevant points for now:

- Each commit is numbered.  The numbers aren't simple counting numbers—they don't go from commit 1 to commit 2 to commit 3—but instead are big ugly hash IDs.  These look random, but aren't: each is actually a cryptographic checksum of the contents of the commit.  You will have seen these hash IDs in `git log` output (or run `git log` now to see them).
- Because of this cryptographic checksum numbering, no part of any commit can ever be changed.  A commit, once made, is totally read-only, and mostly permanent.  (It is possible to get rid of commits, but we won't look at that here.)
- A commit has two parts, its data and its metadata.  The data part holds a full snapshot of every file that Git knew about at the time you (or whoever) made the commit.  The metadata holds information about the commit itself, such as who made it, when, and why: their name, email address, and log message.
- Inside the metadata, Git adds some information that's for Git itself:  Each commit holds the commit number—the hash ID—of its immediate predecessor commit.  Git calls this the *parent* of the commit.  (Most commits have exactly one of these parent IDs, but merge commits, as we'll see, have more.)

Git can look up any commit—or any internal Git object at all—by its hash-ID.  So if we have a hash ID in hand, we say that this *points to* the commit, which Git can now find.  And, because each commit stores the hash ID of its parent, these commits point *backwards*.  This means we can draw a simple linear chain of ordinary commits like so:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

where each uppercase letter stands in for an actual hash ID.  If we know hash ID `H`, we can have Git find the actual commit, which contains both a snapshot of files, and the hash ID of earlier commit `G`.  This lets Git find `G`, which contains a snapshot and hash ID `F`, which lets Git find `F`, and so on.

This is how Git works, in general: backwards, from the *last* commit.  Note that commit `G`, for instance, could not be changed: it can point back to `F` because `F` existed when we (or whoever) made `G`, but `H` did not exist yet, and we won't know `H`'s ID until we make it.  So `G` can point back to `F`, but not forwards to `H`.  `H` can point back to `G`, but not forwards to whatever will come later.

But we still have one problem.  Where will Git get hash ID `H`?  This is where *branch names* come in.

#### A branch name holds one commit hash ID

Given the chain of commits:

```
...--F--G--H
```

Git simply puts hash ID `H` into some *branch name*, such as `master`.  This name then points to commit `H`, making it easy to find:

```
...--G--H   <-- master
```

If we now wish to add a *second* branch name, Git requires us to pick some *existing commit*, and will make the new name point to this commit.  Quite often, we pick the commit we're using right now—e.g., commit `H`:

```
...--G--H   <-- develop, master
```

Now that we have two *names*—for the same commit, at the moment—we need a way to know which name we're actually *using*.  To handle that, Git attaches the special name `HEAD` to just one branch name, so we should update our drawing:

```
...--G--H   <-- develop, master (HEAD)
```

This indicates that while both names pick commit `H`, the name we're using is `master`.  Note that *every commit is on both branches*.

Let's say we now make two *new* commits on `master` (for no apparent reason, but maybe we forgot to switch to `develop` first).  When we make the first new commit, Git will:

- save a snapshot of every file Git knows about;
- add our name and email address as the author and committer, and set the time stamps to "now";
- add our log message;
- use the hash ID of the *current commit* `H` as the parent hash for our new commit;
- write out the new commit, which will thereby get its own unique number, but we'll just call it `I`; and
- **write the new commit's hash ID into the current branch name**.

The result is thus:

```
          I   <-- master (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- develop
```

If we make a second new commit in this state, we get:

```
          I--J   <-- master (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- develop
```

At this point, commits up through `H` are still on both branches, but commits `I` and `J` are only on `master`.

Now let's run `git checkout develop` (or in Git 2.23 and later, `git switch develop` will do the same thing).  This makes our current *branch name* become `develop` and our current *commit* go back to commit `H`:

```
          I--J   <-- master
         /
...--G--H   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

Git will update its internal next-commit files (in Git's *index* aka *staging area*, which we haven't covered here) and our working tree files to match commit `H`, so that we start with the same files that are saved forever in `H`.  If we now make a new commit, we get:

```
          I--J   <-- master
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

Note that each branch name just identifies the one commit: `J` for `master`, and `K` for develop.  Git calls these the *tip commits* of the branches.

Making a second new commit gives us:

```
          I--J   <-- master
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

Commits `K` and `L` are now only on `develop`.  We're now in a situation in which `git merge` makes sense.

#### Real merges

What `git merge` does can be described in just one sentence, but the details get rather complicated.  **Merging is about combining changes.**  But we've just seen that Git doesn't actually *store* changes.  Each commit has a complete snapshot of every file.  So how can Git do this?

Git's answer to this is to go back to the drawings we're making.  These drawings produce a *commit graph*.  By starting from any two commits—typically, two commits found by two branch names—and working *backwards*, Git can find the *best common commit*.  In this case, it's easy to see that commits `H` and `G` and earlier are on both branches.  `H` is the *best* such commit because it's the closest to the two branch-tip commits.

Git calls this best common / shared commit the *merge base*.  To use `git merge`, then, we do two things:

- run `git checkout` to get on one of the two branches, so that `HEAD` is attached to the branch that finds one of the tip commits; then
- run `git merge otherbranch`, so that `git merge` can locate the other tip commit.

Git then finds the merge base on its own.  In our case, we might run:

```
git checkout master
git merge develop
```

which will use `H` as the merge base.

To find what *changed*, Git will use an internal variant of the `git diff` command.  Commit `H`, the merge base, holds a snapshot of all files.  Commit `J`, at the tip of `master`, holds a snapshot of all files as well.  Using `git diff`, Git can *compare* these two snapshots:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-H> <hash-of-J>   # what we changed
```

Then, using `git diff` again, Git can compare `H` vs `L`, to see what they changed on `develop`:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-H> <hash-of-L>   # what they changed
```

Merge's job is now to combine these two sets of changes.  This can include new files being added, and existing files being deleted, though for a more typical merge we might just have one or a few files being "changed by us" and one or a few files being "changed by them".

A *merge conflict* occurs when:

- both we and they made some change(s) to some file, *and*
- Git can't *combine* these two changes on its own.

So if we modify line 42 of file *F1*, and they modify any lines of any other files without touching file *F1*, Git will simply take our version of *F1*, as they didn't change that file.  If they modified file *F2* and we didn't touch it, Git will just take their version of file *F2*.  If we both touched *F3*, though, Git will need to combine our changes—to whatever lines we changed—and their changes.  If those changes *overlap or touch*, Git will declare a merge conflict.

Git will also declare a merge conflict if we deleted a file they modified (or vice versa), or and in various other cases that aren't all that important right now.  Note that deleting a file is a "whole file" change that will automatically conflict, regardless of which lines the other side modified in that file.  But if we deleted a file, and they didn't touch it, Git is fine with that: the combination of our "delete this file", and their "do nothing at all to this file", is to delete the file.

If Git *is* able to combine our changes and their changes, Git applies these combined changes to the snapshot in the merge base—in commit `H`, in this case—and then makes a new *merge commit*, which we will call `M` here.  The new merge commit has a snapshot, like any commit.  It has metadata, like any commit: you are the author and committer and "now" is used for both timestamps.  But, unlike an ordinary commit, the new commit gets *two* parents.  One is the usual: the commit we start from when we run `git merge`, which in this case is commit `J`.  The other is the commit we named on the command line: in this case, commit `L`.  So the resulting merge commit looks like this:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- master (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   <-- develop
```

Again, the *snapshot* in commit `M` is the result of *combining* the `H`-vs-`J` changes with the the `H`-vs-`L` changes.  If Git was able to combine these changes on its own, Git did so, then applied them to the snapshot in `H`.  That kept our changes but also added their changes.

Note that moving back from commit `M`, we will visit not only commit `J`, but also commit `L`.  So now, *all* these commits are on the `master` branch.  The branch gained three commits all at once: new commit `M`, but also commits `K` and `L`, which previously were only on `develop`.

#### Your first issue

> Also I get these "delete mode" and "create mode" messages that I don't understand.

This is Git's way of saying that the combination of your changes and their changes includes deleting some file(s)—Git will tell you *which* file names are being deleted—and creating some other, different files (and again Git will tell you which files).  The *mode* part is the file's mode: either the file is executable (`mode 100755`) or it is not (`mode 100644`).  These are the only two allowed modes.<sup>1</sup>

You can see why Git believes these files were deleted by running one or both of those two `git diff --find-renames` commands yourself.  The tricky part here is to find the hash ID of the merge base commit, but Git has a command that does this:

```
git merge-base --all <name-or-hash-id> <name-or-hash-id>
```

will do the job.  For instance, if you were doing `git merge develop` while on `master` while `master` identified commit `J` and `develop` identified commit `L`, you can find the hash IDs of commits `J` and `L` and use those two as the arguments to `git merge-base --all`.  You can then diff this hash ID against the hash ID of commit `J`, and again against the hash ID of commit `L`.

(Alternatively, if you're willing to take a slight risk of having more than one merge base—the `git merge-base --all` command will find out if this is the case, and if so, you need something a little more complicated, but usually it's not the case—you can use the three-dot syntax built into `git diff`.  For space reasons, I won't go into detail here.)

---

<sup>1</sup>In Git repositories created in 2005, there were more allowable file modes.  This was discovered to be a bad idea and modern Git generates only these two modes, but `git fsck` still permits mode `100664`, for instance, to accommodate these ancient repositories.  Remember that no commit can ever be changed, so these commits that contain `mode 100664` files cannot be fixed.

---

#### Fast-forwards

Sometimes, if you run:

```
git checkout master
git merge develop
```

Git will tell you that it did a *fast-forward*, instead of a merge.  What this means is clearer if we once again draw the commit graph.  Suppose we start out with:

```
...--G--H   <-- master, develop (HEAD)
```

and then add some commits to `develop` in the usual way:

```
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I--J   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

If we now check out `master` and merge `develop`, Git will find the merge base in the usual way: by staring from the two branch tip commits `H` and `J`, and working backwards as needed to find the best *shared* commit.  But this time, after making two steps back from `J`, Git reaches commit `H`, which is the other commit.  So Git can take *zero* steps back from `H`, and hence use `H` as the merge base for this merge.

This merge would:

- diff `H` against itself to see what *we* changed (nothing, of course!); and
- diff `H` against `J` to see what *they* changed; then
- combine nothing with something.

The result of this combining, when applied to commit `H`, would obviously match the snapshot associated with commit `J`.

Hence, in this situation, Git will by default take a short-cut.  It will not bother to *merge* at all.  Instead, it will simply check out the other commit—in this case commit `J`—while dragging the *current branch name* forward, so that we end up with:

```
...--G--H--I--J   <-- master (HEAD), develop
```

You can force Git to make a real merge, using `git merge --no-ff`, which disables the fast-forward short-cut.  This time Git really will compare `H` against itself, compare `H` against `J`, and combine the two sets of changes:

```
...--G--H------K   <-- master (HEAD)
         \    /
          I--J   <-- develop
```

(When and even whether this is useful is somewhat a matter of taste, rather than correctness.)

I think this is the situation you're seeing.  See [j6t's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63585387/1256452) as well, which came in when I was near the end of this.

#### "Already up to date"

There's one more somewhat-interesting merge case.  Suppose you are on some branch, such as `master`, and you run `git merge develop` and get the message `Already up to date.`  What this means is that you have a situation that looks like this:

```
...--G--H   <-- develop
         \
          I--J   <-- master (HEAD)
```

Git computes the merge base as usual, but this time the merge base `H` is *behind* the tip of your current branch `master`.  It is in fact the tip of the other branch.  This also occurs when the two names locate the same commit (e.g., if both names point to `H`, or both to `J`).

#### Conclusion

To see what `git merge` will do:

- **Draw the graph** (or have Git draw it for you; see `git log --graph`, often used with `--all --decorate --oneline`).
- Locate the *merge base* commit and the two tip commits.
- See if the merge base is one or both of the tip commits.  If so, the merge is trivial (fast-forward-able) or already done.
- Otherwise a true merge is needed.  If desired, use `git diff` to see the two sets of changes that will be combined.
- If the sets of changes aren't what you want, inspect the commits that lead up from the merge base to whichever branch tip(s) have some issues in them:

  - What went wrong?
  - How will you prevent this (or at least deter it) in the future?
  - If appropriate, add new commits to one or both branches to fix the problems.

If necessary, consider using `git merge --no-commit` to have Git *start* the merge but not *finish* it.  You can then correct the merge, but note that this produces what some call an [*evil merge*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461909/1256452).  If you ever have Git *repeat* this merge,<sup>2</sup> you'll have to do the same manual fixups.  Or, let Git do the merge, then add a fixup commit.  This has the advantage that if you let Git repeat the merge, it will get the same (bad) result, but you can then have Git repeat the fixup.

---

<sup>2</sup>The old, now-deprecated `git rebase -p` and the newfangled `git rebase -r` command will "copy" merges, much like the way any rebase copies ordinary commits, but unlike ordinary commits, `git cherry-pick` *cannot* copy a merge commit.  So these work by *repeating* the merge instead.  This repetition does not include any flags you specified when you ran the `git merge`, and does not include any manual fixups you made.

Comment: Omg, thank you so much for your time and effort to type all of that down. That makes the merging process a whole lot clearer and also explains why git behaves the way it does. I started from scratch, this time actually having a merge base and it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

> On `mergebranch`, I have the old version of the system that has some custom changes and files that are not in the `update`, but I need them to be in the `updated` version as well.

In Git, you're always merging a branch into the one you currently have checked out. So, if you wanted to bring the changes that are in `mergedbranch` into `updated`, you'd have to merge `mergebranch` into `update` by saying:

```
git checkout update
git merge mergebranch
```

Comment: I tried that as well, but it only tells me that it is already up to date.

Comment: Did you try it before or after you run `git merge update` from `mergebranch`?

Answer (score 0):

## to get some code from branch **branch1** to another **branch2** :

- Checkout to **branch2** : `git checkout branch2`
- Get the code from a remote branch **branch1** by running a pull command: `git pull origin branch1`

## Update

```
git fetch origin
git checkout origin/mergebranch
```

5-2) merge this branch:

```
git merge --no-ff update
```

resolve conflict and correct error if exist then push this version if is perfect into your branch ex : mergebranch

**this new version you ca push it into the master or mergebranch**

```
git push origin mergebranch
```

if you are detached from head message shown then do this instead :

```
git push origin HEAD:mergebranch
```

Comment: I am not sure I understood you correctly. I tried this on the update branch. It says already up to day, although its a different version.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, I think you have this history (time flows left to right):

```
          D--E--F   <-- update
         /
--A--B--C           <-- mergebranch
```

When you issued the merge command, `mergebranch` pointed at commit `C`. This is a so-called fast-forward situation. No actual merge is necessary. Git just repoints `mergebranch` to commit `F`, so that it is equal to branch `update`.

```
          D--E--F   <-- update, mergebranch
         /
--A--B--C
```

An actual merge operation would have been required if the two branches had truly diverged like this:

```
          D--E--F   <-- update
         /
--A--B--C
         \
          X--Y      <-- mergebranch
```

In this situation, a merge commit would have been created:

```
          D--E--F   <-- update
         /       \
--A--B--C         M <-- mergebranch
         \       /
          X-----Y
```

When commits `D`, `E`, and `F` remove some files and add other files, then these removals and additions are mirrored in the final state of branch `mergebranch`, regardless of whether the operation was a fast-forward or a real merge, because with the command

```
git merge update
```

you say: "I want all changes between when branch `updated` forked off from the current branch (`C`) and the tip of branch `updated` (`F`) integrated into the current branch."

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what happened. Now it all makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved thanks to everyone's comments.

So what I was missing was the merge base. I started from scratch with the original version of the system and from there created two new branches, one for the custom old version and one for the update. From there, the merging process worked just as I expected.