# Is there a way to merge a branch and amend it to the last commit, so that it won't create an extra commit?

Tags: git

Here is the scenario:

`git commit -m 'something'` *1 commit overall*

`git commit --amend` 1 *commit overall*

`git merge develop` *now there's 2 commits **:(***

Is there a way to merge develop and amend it to the last commit, so that it won't create an extra commit?

Comment: Commits represent your repo's history. Why do you want/need to create a lying history? If you actually merged these branches, why would you want history to say otherwise? It'll only making future investigations harder.

Comment: You could consider using `rebase`, but this command has its own drawbacks which you should be aware of.

Comment: @RomainValeri i know what i'm doing... thanks

Comment: @kosist rebase can result in missing files

Comment: @UFCInsider, merge also could result in missing files. `rebase` and `merge` do similar task - they merge history of one branch into another, but the difference is that `rebase` kind of "replays" changes on target branch. Check this tutorial - https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing.

Comment: I'm sorry if my first comment sounded condescending, I was (and still am) suspecting an XY problem. Just trying to help.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not all that well formed, which means the answer is going to be rather long and perhaps inconclusive and unhelpful.  But, well, here goes.   You *may* be looking for `git merge --squash`, but you *may* be engaged in a [snipe hunt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snipe_hunt).

An actual merge normally creates a merge commit.  A merge commit has two parents, by definition.<sup>1</sup>  Of course, the first statement requires defining what I mean by *actual merge*, but before we go there, let's look at `git commit --amend`, since that command *seems* to be the focus of your question.  (The emphasis here on *seems* is because, [as RomainValeri noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64350853/is-there-a-way-to-merge-a-branch-and-amend-it-to-the-last-commit-so-that-it-won#comment113795247_64350853), this may be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/641754).)

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, a merge commit has two *or more* parents.

The word *merge*, in Git, is both a verb—*to merge*, the action of combining work—and an adjective or noun.  As an adjective, *merge commit*, it modifies the word *commit*, and as a noun, *a merge*, it is short-hand for the phrase *merge commit*.  In the noun or adjective case it refers to a commit with at least two parents.  Such commits are made by `git merge` under certain conditions, which we'll describe below.

---

#### `git commit` vs `git commit --amend`

The `git commit` command builds a new commit.  In general—ignoring options like `--only` or `--include`, which complicate the picture—this works by:

1. gathering any metadata needed for the new commit, such as your name and email address and a log message;
2. using `git write-tree` to turn the index into a snapshot, producing a tree hash ID;
3. using `git commit-tree` to create a new commit with the tree hash ID from step 2 and the metadata from step 1, plus the appropriate parent hash IDs; and
4. writing the resulting commit hash ID from step 3 into the current branch name (attached `HEAD`) or `HEAD` itself (detached `HEAD`).

The `--amend` flag affects the way that Git gets the "appropriate" parent hash IDs for step 3.

In most cases, the (single) appropriate hash ID is the hash ID to which the name `HEAD` resolves: that is, we just run `git rev-parse HEAD` and we have the right hash ID.  If we're committing a merge, however—as indicated by the presence of a `MERGE_HEAD` pseudo-ref—then the appropriate hash IDs, plural, are the one from `git rev-parse HEAD` plus the one from `git rev-parse MERGE_HEAD`.  Hence, if the merge-as-a-verb process from `git merge` fails due to merge conflicts, and the person driving Git has fixed up those conflicts and runs `git commit`, `git commit` will now make a merge-as-an-adjective commit.  This *concludes* the merge, so `git commit` will now *remove* the `MERGE_HEAD` pseudo-ref (`git update-ref -d MERGE_HEAD`).<sup>2</sup>

With `--amend`, we tell `git commit` that instead of using `HEAD` to find the (single) parent of the new commit, it should use the commit hash IDs *in* the current commit.  That is, instead of `git rev-parse HEAD` it should use `git rev-parse HEAD^@` (see the `^@` suffix in [the gitrevisons documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions)), knowing that this may produce more than one hash ID.

It's not obvious what `--amend` *should* do when concluding a merge, but [the source code](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d4a392452e292ff924e79ec8458611c0f679d6d4/builtin/commit.c#L474-L481) has the answer: it's simply forbidden.  This completely sidesteps the "what should we do" question, by saying "we don't".  We can only use `--amend` when we do a normal commit, not when we conclude a merge.

---

<sup>2</sup>The commit command can also finish a cherry-pick, including a cherry-pick from an ongoing rebase, or a revert, which internally is also a cherry-pick.  See [the possible "whence" values listed in `wt-status.h`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d4a392452e292ff924e79ec8458611c0f679d6d4/wt-status.h#L37-L44).

---

#### Actual merges

It's time to define the phrase *actual merge*.  What exactly do I mean by this phrase?  I'm afraid the easy definition is overly circular: an actual merge is one where the result is a merge commit, and a merge commit is one made by an actual merge.  It's not *completely* circular since we also know that a *merge commit* is one with two or more parents, but it's also not quite *accurate* because I'm using *actual merge* a bit sloppily (on purpose) so that I can get to `git merge --squash`.  We can use that to work backwards.  Let's look at this a different way, and define *actual merge* in terms of the process that `git merge` itself kicks off.

When you run `git merge`, you give it options and arguments.  Ignoring the options for now, let's look at the simple case of:

```
git merge thing
```

where `thing` is either a branch name or a commit hash ID.  In fact, if `thing` *is* a branch name, `git merge` runs `git rev-parse` on it to *get* its hash ID, keeping the branch name only for building the default log message: it's the hash ID that matters for the rest of the job.  So this really devolves into `git merge hash-id`.

Git now uses the *current commit* hash ID, as from `git rev-parse HEAD`, and this other hash ID to inspect the *commit graph*.  It uses a [Lowest Common Ancestor algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_ancestor) to find the *merge base* commit of these two commits.  Ideally, this produces a single commit hash ID: if it produces more than one hash ID, we have to get into the `-s resolve` vs `-s recursive` *merge strategies*.  So let's just ignore that case, along with the one where there is no merge base commit at all.

Having found the (single) merge base commit, we now have three cases:

- The merge base commit *is* the other commit.  The other commit is already merged; `git merge` says there is nothing to do, and quits.  (This includes the case when the current and other commit are the same commit.)
- The merge base commit is the *current* commit.  The other commit is strictly ahead of this commit, and `git merge` *can* do a fast-forward merge.
- The merge base commit is behind both the current commit *and* the other commit.  A true merge is required, and `git merge` will do an actual merge.

If a fast-forward merge is possible, Git *won't* do an actual merge by default, but by adding `--no-ff` to the `git merge` arguments, Git *will* do an actual merge.  So this gets us a definition of *actual merge:* it's one where a merge commit is either *required*, or forced through `--no-ff`, from a `git merge` command that finds a merge base that's not the other commit.

All of this is a rather long-winded way of arriving at my real meaning of *actual merge*, which is: a `git merge` command that invokes the *to merge*, or *merge as a verb*, action.  The *merge as a verb* action is what we want to consider here.  It has three inputs:

- the *merge base* commit, as found by `git merge` when it checked to see if there was something to merge and decided that fast-forwarding (instead of merging) was either impossible, or forbidden by command-line flags;
- the *current commit*, whose hash ID has been found via the name `HEAD`; and
- the *other* commit, whose hash ID was the argument to `git merge` (or `git merge` found it from a branch name).

The merge-as-a-verb process now compares the merge base snapshot with each of the other two commits' snapshots, to find out what changed, and then combines these changes and applies the combined changes to the merge base snapshot.<sup>3</sup>  We'll ignore this process entirely, except to note that it can have a *merge conflict*.

If it does have a merge conflict, it stops, leaving a bit of a mess in your working tree—you can use this to finish the merge, if you like—and whatever it successfully merged in its own index, which is where it will look when you use `git commit` to conclude the merge later.  What it failed to resolve stays in its index, in slots that mark the merge as unresolved.  As you resolve each conflict, you will un-mark those slots, usually with `git add`.<sup>4</sup>

If there are no merge conflicts, the merge—as represented by running a *merge strategy* (see footnote 3)—finishes the merge in Git's index, and `git merge` normally now makes a *merge commit* on its own.

---

<sup>3</sup>This glosses over the role of the *merge strategy*.  In particular the `-s ours` strategy doesn't combine anything at all.  It just takes the snapshot from the "ours" (`HEAD`) commit.  Some strategies also take more than one "other commit": `-s ours` and `-s octopus` both do so.  Tossing the strategy stuff into the mix here, however, makes the process obscure, and probably does not matter for the original question.

<sup>4</sup>If you use `git mergetool`, the `git mergetool` code will run the `git add` step for you, under various conditions.

---

#### Using `--no-commit`

The merge-as-a-verb process combines work in two different branches.  It does so *by* **comparing** a single common snapshot, as stored in the merge base commit, to two different snapshots, as stored in the `--ours` (`HEAD`) commit and `--theirs` (other) commit.  These comparisons produce two line-by-line diffs, and Git applies simple text-combining rules to combine the diffs and apply those combined diffs to the files that are stored in the merge-base commit.

This process doesn't always work.  Git has no idea about the *semantics* of the input files, and line-by-line combining may be the wrong thing to do.  If the result isn't right, the merge commit that Git makes might not be what you wanted.  It might be *close* to what you wanted, but maybe you'd like to have `git merge` stop *before* committing, so that you can check.  If you find that Git's merge was close, but needs some tweaking, you *can* fix it up,<sup>5</sup>
and then run `git commit` or `git merge --continue` to conclude the merge.<sup>6</sup>

Using `git merge --no-commit` makes `git merge` stop *before* committing, the same way it *would* stop if the merge-as-a-verb process failed.  Since the process didn't actually *fail*, the copies of files in your working tree and in Git's index are all successfully merged, but since it did *stop*, you can edit the files in your working tree, and then use `git add` to copy the edited files back into Git's index.  So this allows you to make the final merge commit without having to use `git commit --amend` later.

The result, of course, is the same even if you *do* allow `git merge` to make the commit on its own, then discover some bugs and fix them up and use `git commit --amend`, because `--amend` will *keep both parents* when you use it on a merge commit.  So, presumably, `--no-commit` isn't the option that you want for this particular problem.

---

<sup>5</sup>There are drawbacks and dangers here, mostly having to do with the potential need to *repeat* a merge later, or so-called *evil merges*.  That does not mean *never do it*, but rather, *be aware*.  See also [Evil merges in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461909/1256452)

<sup>6</sup>`git merge --continue` simply checks that there is an ongoing merge—that the `MERGE_HEAD` pseudo-ref exists—and then literally runs `git commit`.  It's just a sort of safety check, to make sure you *are* doing what you *think* you are doing.

---

#### Using `--squash`

The `--squash` option is similar to the `--no-commit` option, with one extra feature.  It not only *stops the merge from committing*, it also *removes the `MERGE_HEAD` pseudo-ref* (or never creates it, really).  This means your eventual `git commit`, to conclude the merge, makes a *non-merge commit*.  The commit that your `git commit` makes is an ordinary, single-parent commit.

(It's kind of odd that this stops the commit: `git merge --squash` should just omit the pseudo-ref and commit.  If you want it not to make the commit too, you could run `git merge --squash --no-commit`.  The two options make sense either stand-alone or combined: there's no need to make `git merge --squash` combine them.  The only reason for Git to work this way is that it was convenient to *write*, back in the days when this stuff was all just shell scripts.)

Note that the result is that the merged branch isn't merged after all.  In the typical merge case, we start with:

```
       I--J   <-- ours (HEAD)
      /
...--H
      \
       K--L   <-- theirs
```

and end up with:

```
       I--J
      /    \
...--H      M   <-- ours (HEAD)
      \    /
       K--L   <-- theirs
```

This is *how we know that `theirs` is merged*.  With `git merge --squash`, though, we end up with:

```
       I--J--S   <-- ours (HEAD)
      /
...--H
      \
       K--L   <-- theirs
```

where the *snapshot* in commit `S` matches the *snapshot* we would have in commit `M`, had we made commit `M`.  But commit `S` has just a single parent, `J`, instead of two parents `J` and `L`.  It is therefore impossible to know for sure, later, whether commit `L` was actually merged in.  The only thing that is sensible to do with the `theirs` branch at this point is to delete it entirely:

```
       I--J--S   <-- ours (HEAD)
      /
...--H
      \
       K--L   ???
```

Now that we can't *find* commits `K-L`, we won't wonder whether they were ever merged.  But since commits `K-L` might exist in many other Git repositories—Git spreads commits to other Git repositories like they were viruses—they could come back to haunt us later (like viruses).  It's very hard, but usually pretty important, to make sure they're stamped out everywhere, if you're going to squash like this.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Will get to the down of all this soon and comment again