# Squash a merge commit with the first commit on a branch

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-squash

I have a commit and a merge commit after it. I want to squash the merge commit with the first commit on the same branch. Can someone explain how this can be done?

[Screenshot of git rebase -i -r](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrX6G.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Merge commits cannot be squashed.  The definition of "squashing" a commit starts with separate commits `A` and `B` that have a parent/child relationship such that `A` is the parent and `B` is the child:

```
...--o--A--B--C--...
```

(with older commits drawn towards the left, and newer ones towards the right).

We then replace the `A-B` pair with a single combined commit `AB`:

```
       A--B--C--...
      /
...--o--AB--C'--...
```

where the parent of `AB` is the same as the parent of `A`, but the snapshot of `AB` is the same as the snapshot of `B`.  Because `AB` has a different hash ID than both `A` and `B`, we are forced to replace all "downstream" commits, such as `C`, with new commits `C'` and so on.  The original commit stream `...-A-B-C` continues to exist, but we stop *using* it in favor of the new-and-improved stream.

What makes a commit a *merge commit* is that it has not just one, but rather two or more parents.  That is, we might have:

```
...--o--A--B   <-- branch1 (HEAD)
          /
         C   <-- branch2
```

Git is not currently capable of replacing `B` with a merge `AB` that (1) has the same parent*s* (`o` and `C`) as `A` *and `B`*, but (2) the same snapshot as `B`.  What we would like to get here is:

```
...--o--AB   <-- branch1 (HEAD)
       /
      C   <-- branch2
```

*Humans* can do this, but currently Git has no command built into it to do this.

To do this manually:

1. get into *detached HEAD* state at commit `o`, with `git checkout` or `git switch --detach`;
2. prepare the merge commit message for new commit `AB` in `/tmp/msgfile`;
3. run `git merge --ff-only $(git commit-tree -p HEAD -p branch2 -F /tmp/msgfile branch1^{tree})` to make commit `AB` as a merge commit and fast-forward to it;
4. run `git checkout -B branch1` or `git switch -C branch1` to make the name `branch1` point to commit `AB`.

Note that this particular recipe assumes that there are no commits beyond `B` on `branch1`.  If there are, the recipe gets more complex.

One last note: the result of doing this is likely to be what people call an [evil merge](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461909/1256452).  Be sure you understand this, and whether it is reasonable to do that with your particular project, co-workers, etc.  *Re-performing* the merge, as `git rebase -r` would do later, is likely to produce a different result: that of dropping commit `A` entirely.