# how to squash last two commits into a merge commit

Tags: git, git-merge, git-squash

this is my git log history, I want to squash my last two commits into "merge release into feature" commit (which is a merge commit)

I tried with `git rebase -i HEAD~3`
and keep getting this error "cannot squash without a previous commit error"

```
commit 6a4fc (HEAD -> tasl-sq1)
Author: john
Date:   date

   show logo on landing page if they have one

commit dfa4fc
Author: James 
Date:   date

   update ui

commit 398ec03
Merge: efd12143ab c57bf64b81
Author: Tom
Date:   date

    merge release into feature 

commit dddfc 
Author: KAle
Date:   date

    API update
```

Comment: [j6t's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68347928/1256452) is *how to achieve this*, but I will add that the result is generally what people call an [evil merge](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461909/1256452), which (correctly) suggests that you should be cautious about using this.

Answer (score 3):

In this situation it is a very simple matter of

```
git reset --soft 398ec03
git commit --amend
```

i.e., you go back to the merge commit without wiping the staged files nor the working tree, and then you amend the merge commit.

Answer (score 0):

I know of a hacky way to do this :

- reset (with `reset --soft`) to the first parent of the merge commit
- create a file `.git/MERGE_HEAD` with the hash of the other commit to merge
- run `git commit`

```
# move back to "before the merge", while keeping all the current content as staged
git reset --soft efd12143ab

# indicate to git 'I want to merge c57bf64b81'
echo c57bf64b81 >> .git/MERGE_HEAD

# commit
git commit
```

Comment: @j6t's answer is simpler than this one. I will leave my answer as I think the `MERGE_HEAD` indication may help in other situations.