# Why merging master branch to feature branch is deleting files from feature branch in GIT?

Tags: git, github, merge, version-control

I have a feature branch A and I have done few commits in the feature branch. My master branch is ahead of my feature branch. When I am trying to merge my master branch to feature branch , my feature branch files which are committed and pushed to remote of my feature branch gets deleted. I am getting no merge conflict while merging master to feature branch. When I delete the local feature branch and checkout again from remote of feature branch, those deleted files reappear but as soon as I merge updated master(without changes from this feature branch A), the files gets deleted. Can someone help me out as what is happening ?

Comment: Are those changed files removed on master branch? Otherwise, I don't have any other idea how it is possible since you didn't have merge conflicts

Comment: That would be expected if the files are deleted in `master`. Is that the case?

Comment: No. The files are not deleted on master but on feature branch. It is as follows :
Step 1 -> Feature branch has a file1 committed and pushed on Feature remote branch
Step 2 -> Check out to master and update master.
Step 3 -> Check out to Feature branch .
Step 4-> Before merging updated master to feature branch files are present but as soon as I merge updated master to feature branch, files get deleted.

Comment: I am wondering if you are started your work on a different branch than you thought - just a guess. However, have you tried running "git rebase origin/master" instead of trying to merge? (I assume you have pushed your branch to github anyway, so the fact that this is destructive locally is not irreversible)

Answer (score 1):

The `git merge` command performs a "true merge" by:

1. Locating the *merge base* commit.  If you are on branch *`B`* now, and are running `git merge M`, you can find this commit's hash ID(s) yourself with:

   ```
   git merge-base --all B M
   ```

   Ideally, this prints just one commit hash ID; if it prints two or more hash IDs, you have an especially complex merge and must move to a more detailed answer.
2. Using the equivalent of `git diff --find-renames` twice.  One of these `diff` commands figures out what *you* changed on branch *`B`*.  The other diff figures out what *they* changed on branch *`M`*.
3. Combining these changes.

Your result, of combining these changes, includes deleting some file(s).  You'll see that, in the two `diff`s generated in step 2, one of those two `diff`s says to delete some file, and other of the two `diff`s says nothing at all about that file.  The result of combining the *delete file xyz* instruction with the *do nothing at all* instruction is *delete file xyz*, so Git follows that (combined) instruction and deletes the file.

If you don't want the file deleted, don't have deleted it.  Figure out *why* one of these two diffs shows the file as deleted.  You can run the two diffs yourself; you might wish to use `--name-status` to cut down on the amount of output.  (You can cut down on it even further with `--diff-filter`, but start with just `--name-status`.)  For instance, suppose that `git merge-base` prints `12604a8d0c0a7d706c7be7be607a584260042ca9`.  You would run:

```
git diff --find-renames --name-status 12604a8d0c0a7d706c7be7be607a584260042ca9 HEAD
```

to see what Git thinks *you* changed (you can type in `B`'s branch name instead of `HEAD` if you like), and:

```
git diff --find-renames --name-status 12604a8d0c0a7d706c7be7be607a584260042ca9 M
```

(substitute in the actual branch name) to find out what Git thinks *they* changed.

If you don't like Git's merge result:

- make changes (by adding commits to either or both branches) before merging; or
- make changes (by adding new commits) *after* merging; or
- use `git merge --no-commit` and make an [evil merge](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461909/1256452).  Read the linked question, and think hard about why you want an evil merge, before making one, because if you use some of Git's fancier options to *re-perform* this merge later, Git will make a non-evil merge next time, unless you carefully arrange to make the same evil merge.  This tends to require a lot of knowing-what-you-are-doing.

Note that `git merge` sometimes doesn't perform any merges at all, and some results *from* `git merge` (e.g., with `--squash`) are not *merge commits*, even though they may have used the merge machinery to produce merged results.  The noun-phrase *merge commit* is a very different thing from the verb *to merge*.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the reason for this issue. The files were added to master in past and were deleted so when I was trying to merge master to feature branch, GIT used to ignore those files. I fixed that by following below steps :

1. Make some changes to those files.
2. Git commit those files.
3. Merge master to feature branch.