# How to efficiently review GIT auto-merge results on Windows?

Tags: git

I recently learned, that [GIT auto-merging can produce undesireable results in certain situations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68557395/why-does-this-git-merge-not-result-in-conflicts). So, I am looking for an efficient way to review auto-merged files. So far, I have tried the Visual Studio 2017 GIT client, which gives no information whatsoever about auto-merging, and Tortoise GIT, which at least shows the names of all auto-merged files in the merge-progress-window, but lacks the functionality to open the three-way-diff for such a file directly from the merge-progress-window.

How do you review auto-merge results? Do you know any (windows based) tools that let you review auto-merge results? What is the recommended workflow here?

Comment: I don't like the fancy tools. [The more they overthink the plumbing, the easier it is to stop up the drain.](https://www.azquotes.com/quote/633900) I just run `git diff` to compare the desired two commits (usually HEAD^ vs HEAD to see what happened to "my code").

Comment: @torek, this is not an option with bigger pull-requests, 'though. The changeset will be so huge that you don't want to review every single file.

Comment: A pull request too big to review is too big to accept. The sender should break it into manageable pieces.

Comment: Sorry, I said pull-request, but what I actually meant were big merges. I agree that the pull-requests should be rather small, but the resulting merge could still be big, depending on how much work has been done on the target branch. And the merge is precisely what I want to review.