# Git commit history of a file: showing the right commits

Tags: git, logging, merge, commit, history

I do have the following alias, to show me the commit history of any given file:

```
file-history = log --follow --date-order --date=short -C
```

It works well, but never shows "merge commits", while the file can have been modified in a branch we did merge into main, for example.

[image]

The solution is to add the option *-m*, but then it shows many, many, many merge commits, for which most of them seem unrelated to the commit history of the file.

What is the right way to write such an alias to make it behave correctly (like in BitBucket, for this matter): **showing all commits that did change a file, and only those?**

**EXTRA INFORMATION --**

Using *-m* shows way too many commits; concretely:

[image]

(In red rectangles, what I should see... that's what BitBucket displays...)

(BTW, I don't understand why the commit da3c94a1 is duplicated.)

Using *-c* shows even much more commits (the first commit that should be reported being in the bottom of the page) and displays the diffs (what I don't want to see here):

[image]

Same results for *--cc*:

[image]

And *--first-parent* shows weird results (as I don't see at all the commits I'm interested in):

[image]

**NEW EXTRA INFORMATION --**

And, with *--first-parent -m*, no change:

[image]

**ANSWER TO TOREK --**

To make things simpler, I've created the following test repo:

```
    master    master
     C--D      I--J
    /    \    /    \
A--B      G--H      M--N  master
    \    /    \    /
     E--F      K--L
     br1       br2
```

where I did merge `br1` and `br2` onto `master`.

I've created commits which only changed one file at a time.

Commits which changed file1 (only):

- `A`
- `C`
- `F`
- `I`
- `L`

Commits which changed file2 (only):

- `B`
- `D`
- `E`
- `H`
- `J`
- `K`
- `N`

Commits which changed both files:

- `G` (the merge of `br1` onto `master`)
- `M` (the merge of `br2` onto `master`)

Let's begin with the tests:

```
$ git log --decorate --date=short
2021-11-05 d670be5 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) Commit N
2021-11-05 838f65c Merge branch 'br2' (Commit M)
2021-11-05 7ae0238 (br2) Commit L
2021-11-05 affed14 Commit K
2021-11-05 ecd490f Commit J
2021-11-05 ca2e68f Commit I
2021-11-05 45d8231 Commit H
2021-11-05 eb356b8 Merge branch 'br1'
2021-11-05 9aaa030 (br1) Commit F
2021-11-05 552a403 Commit E
2021-11-05 86a71ff Commit D
2021-11-05 611bef2 Commit C
2021-11-05 eceafb8 Commit B
2021-11-05 e137033 Initial commit
```

You know what?  I was expecting to see this instead:

```
2021-11-05 d670be5 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) Commit N
2021-11-05 838f65c Merge branch 'br2' (Commit M)
2021-11-05 ecd490f Commit J
2021-11-05 ca2e68f Commit I
2021-11-05 45d8231 Commit H
2021-11-05 eb356b8 Merge branch 'br1'
2021-11-05 86a71ff Commit D
2021-11-05 611bef2 Commit C
2021-11-05 eceafb8 Commit B
2021-11-05 e137033 Initial commit
```

That is, I was expecting to see neither commits `E` and `F` from `br1` nor `K` and `L`
from `br2`.  So, *it seems I don't undertand everything...*

Now, let's look at the file history of `file2.txt`... Both GitHub and BitBucket --
I've tested both of them -- show me the following commits (and only those) when
asked to display the history of the file:

- `B`
- `D`
- `E`
- `G`
- `H`
- `J`
- `K`
- `M`
- `N`

This is 1 of the 2 results I would have expected -- the other one being the
same without commits `E` and `K`, as I could have thought they would be hidden (as
being part of branches, not committed on `master`).

Now, let's play with some "file history" commands:

```
$ git log --follow --date-order --date=short -C file2.txt
2021-11-05 d670be5 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) Commit N
2021-11-05 affed14 Commit K
2021-11-05 ecd490f Commit J
2021-11-05 45d8231 Commit H
2021-11-05 552a403 Commit E
2021-11-05 86a71ff Commit D
2021-11-05 eceafb8 Commit B

$ git log --follow --date-order --date=short -C -m file2.txt
2021-11-05 d670be5 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) Commit N
2021-11-05 838f65c Merge branch 'br2' (Commit M)
2021-11-05 838f65c Merge branch 'br2' (Commit M)
2021-11-05 affed14 Commit K
2021-11-05 ecd490f Commit J
2021-11-05 45d8231 Commit H
2021-11-05 eb356b8 Merge branch 'br1'
2021-11-05 eb356b8 Merge branch 'br1'
2021-11-05 552a403 Commit E
2021-11-05 86a71ff Commit D
2021-11-05 eceafb8 Commit B

$ git log --follow --date-order --date=short -C -c -s file2.txt
2021-11-05 d670be5 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) Commit N
2021-11-05 838f65c Merge branch 'br2' (Commit M)
2021-11-05 affed14 Commit K
2021-11-05 ecd490f Commit J
2021-11-05 45d8231 Commit H
2021-11-05 eb356b8 Merge branch 'br1'
2021-11-05 552a403 Commit E
2021-11-05 86a71ff Commit D
2021-11-05 eceafb8 Commit B

$ git log --follow --date-order --date=short -C --cc -s file2.txt
2021-11-05 d670be5 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) Commit N
2021-11-05 838f65c Merge branch 'br2' (Commit M)
2021-11-05 affed14 Commit K
2021-11-05 ecd490f Commit J
2021-11-05 45d8231 Commit H
2021-11-05 eb356b8 Merge branch 'br1'
2021-11-05 552a403 Commit E
2021-11-05 86a71ff Commit D
2021-11-05 eceafb8 Commit B

$ git log --follow --date-order --date=short -C -m --first-parent file2.txt
2021-11-05 d670be5 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) Commit N
2021-11-05 838f65c Merge branch 'br2' (Commit M)
2021-11-05 ecd490f Commit J
2021-11-05 45d8231 Commit H
2021-11-05 eb356b8 Merge branch 'br1'
2021-11-05 86a71ff Commit D
2021-11-05 eceafb8 Commit B

$ git log --follow --date-order --date=short -C --cc --full-history -s file2.txt
2021-11-05 d670be5 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) Commit N
2021-11-05 838f65c Merge branch 'br2' (Commit M)
2021-11-05 affed14 Commit K
2021-11-05 ecd490f Commit J
2021-11-05 45d8231 Commit H
2021-11-05 eb356b8 Merge branch 'br1'
2021-11-05 552a403 Commit E
2021-11-05 86a71ff Commit D
2021-11-05 eceafb8 Commit B
```

Let's analyse the results, one by one:

```
$ git log --follow --date-order --date=short -C file2.txt
```

does not show the merge commits. Incomplete results. Failure, then.

```
$ git log --follow --date-order --date=short -C -m file2.txt
```

does show all commits where `file2.txt` has been changed, but duplicates the merge
commits. Partial failure...

```
$ git log --follow --date-order --date=short -C -c -s file2.txt
```

and

```
$ git log --follow --date-order --date=short -C --cc -s file2.txt
```

both show the 9 commits (7 "normal" + 2 merge) where `file2.txt` has been
changed. Same results as on BitBucket and GitHub.

```
$ git log --follow --date-order --date=short -C -m --first-parent file2.txt
```

shows all commits on `master` where `file2.txt` has been changed, and the merge
commits. Could be the other expected results I had, but not the same as
BitBucket and GitHub. Let's discard it, then.

```
$ git log --follow --date-order --date=short -C --cc --full-history -s file2.txt
```

also shows the 9 commits.

So, the commands that give the same (complete) results as the ones from GitHub
and BitBucket are:

```
$ git log --follow --date-order --date=short -C -c -s file2.txt
$ git log --follow --date-order --date=short -C --cc -s file2.txt
$ git log --follow --date-order --date=short -C --cc --full-history -s file2.txt
```

Coming back to my request, which may have been badly expressed, it is the
following: I do want to see all commits that did change some file, in order to
display the other files also changed in the same commits, and doing so discover
the list of files I do have to change for some specific functional request.

Based on my real-world example, it seems that BitBucket was correctly
identifying those commits, and that my `file-history` alias(es) did not... either
showing not enough commits, too much commits, or even inappropriate ones...

Coming back to that real-world example, the following commands:

```
$ git log --follow --date-order --date=short -C -c -s 32-factures-creation.R | wc -l
$ git log --follow --date-order --date=short -C --cc -s 32-factures-creation.R | wc -l
$ git log --follow --date-order --date=short -C --cc --full-history -s 32-factures-creation.R | wc -l
```

all return me 440 lines:

```
2021-10-18 d5590007 Merge branch 'master' of https://bitbucket.org/.../...
2021-10-18 6ccde740 Merge branch 'master' of https://bitbucket.org/.../...
2021-10-06 9d532874 Merge branch 'indexation-RMMMG-09-2021' into release/21.10
2021-10-04 d982c3d8 Merge branch 'indexation-RMMMG-09-2021' into release/21.10
2021-10-04 0a65134f Merge branch 'indexation-RMMMG-09-2021' into release/21.10
2021-10-02 728897b9 Merge branch 'indexation-RMMMG-09-2021' into release/21.10
2021-09-30 0df507b9 Simplify SQL expression in 32-factures-creation.R
2021-09-30 16f94a10 Update format of prsAnneeMois
2021-09-29 f9a6cafb Update "Facturation à l'employeur"
2021-10-02 22ef1194 Merge branch 'feature/103-upgrade-...-logo' into release/21.10
2021-09-20 9a2244d3 (tag: xxx_21-10-20_23-01-50, tag: sh_21-10-20_22-56-11, tag: sh_21-10-20_22-54-54, tag: 2021.10.20_23.04_xxx) Merge branch 'master' of https://bitbucket.org/mc.../...
2021-09-20 9fa77b1e Merge branch 'new-new-augm-eff'
2021-07-02 b4538cce Merge branch 'new-augm-eff' into release/21.07
2021-07-02 20c72364 (tag: 2021.07.01) Merge branch 'master' of https://bitbucket.org/.../...
...
```

That's way more than what I see on BitBucket:

```
2021-09-30 0df507b9 Simplify SQL expression in 32-factures-creation.R
2021-09-30 16f94a10 Update format of prsAnneeMois
2021-09-29 f9a6cafb Update "Facturation à l'employeur"
...
```

So, above, I still see too many commits. Still puzzled...

Comment: Add `-m`, `-c`, or `--cc` to your `git log`. See the documentation for `git diff` on what these options do. The problem with `-m` is that it will (as you've seen) probably show many merge commits: any merge commit in which the file differs from *either* parent will show up here.

Comment: Alternatively, consider traversing *only* the main line with `--first-parent`, skipping any merged side branches entirely. Then `-m` will do what you want (as will `-c` and `--cc`, I think, although I have not tested this).

Comment: Dear @torek, as you see, the alternative options don't work: they show too many commits, and some of them even display full diffs (what's not desired here)... ;-(

Comment: The `-c` and `--cc` options should not do that as they discard any file that matches at least one parent. The `-m` option, however, *will* do that (show more merges than you wish to look at), because you're getting two separate comparisons of the result of the merge: one with respect to the first parent, and one with respect to the second. So if the merged result differs from *either* parent (after stripping it down to just the files of interest), `-m` will show it.

Comment: I do see your output, but that's not surprising here. You'd need to add `-s` to suppress the actual diff while keeping the `-c` or `--cc`. Both of these will make sure that an ["evil merge"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461909/1256452) will show up.

Comment: One last note about `-m`: this "virtually splits" the merge. Remember that all commits hold snapshots. This is true of merge commits as well. All commits have some set of parent commits; for *most* commits, that's a single parent. So `git log -p` and `git show` work by *comparing* the parent (singular) to the child (the commit you're showing, with `git show`). Files that *do* match get ignored; files that *don't* match get diffed, and you see the diff. That's straightforward so far. But now we introduce merges.

Comment: A merge commit has *two* (or more, but let's stop at 2) parents. Which parent(s) should we compare? With `git log`, the answer is: *This is too hard, let's not compare at all. Moving on...* That's why with `git log` you don't see the merges. Adding options (`-m`, `-c`, `--cc`) directs `git log` to try harder. The options say what to do about these two-parent situations. With `-c` and `--cc`, Git will do a *combined diff* by comparing each parent to the child, one at a time, then mashing all the diffs together into one "combined diff".

Comment: There are a bunch of pluses and minuses to this, which require a whole separate discussion. With `-m`, however, Git will do *one diff at a time per parent*, so `git log` will first compare P#1 vs C, then P#2 vs C. That's two `git diff`s and hence you will see the merge commit twice, if both diffs show a difference.

Comment: That's all for `git log -p` of course, which actually shows you the patch. You want to *suppress* the patch (`-s`), but still *note the commit if the diff would have mentioned that file* (`git log <options> -- <file>`). So we have to get `git log` to *do* the diff (with the option), suppress the output (`-s`), and show the commit if the file shows up in the diff. With `-m`, there are *two* diffs (because two parents) and the merge may therefore show up twice.

Comment: @torek, there's no improvement with *--first-parent*, as you can see in the new section added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You asked specifically about looking for merge commits in your output.  I think now, based on all the comments under the question, this was a mistake: you don't *want* the merge commits *at all*, even if they do change the file in question.  What you want is to *stop `git log` from performing History Simplification*.

To do that, simply provide the `--full-history` flag to `git log`.  But it's also important to know *what this flag means:* in particular, I don't think you understand what Git is trying to show you here (which is not surprising, as Git documentation does a terrible job of explaining what Git is trying to do in the first place).

To get to the [aha! moment](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aha%20moment), we have to start with a simple review of stuff probably already know but may have shoved into the back of your mind and forgotten about:

- Git is all about *commits*, and each commit is a numbered entity, found by its big ugly random-looking hash ID;
- each commit stores a *snapshot* and some *metadata,* and the metadata include the raw hash ID of some set of earlier commits; and
- *most* commits store just *one* previous commit hash ID.

This makes commits form simple backwards-looking chains.  Let's use simple uppercase letters as pretend hash IDs, and allocate them sequentially to make things easy for our puny human brains, and imagine we have a repository that ends with a commit with hash ID `H`, like this:

```
A <-B <-C ... <-F <-G <-H
```

That is, the *last*—and therefore latest—commit in this repository is commit `H`.  Commit `H` stores both a full snapshot of every file *and* a backwards-pointing arrow (really, the true commit hash ID of) earlier commit `G`.

Using the stored snapshot in `G` *and* the stored snapshot in `H`, Git can *compare* the two snapshots.  Whatever is different here, those are the files we changed; by comparing those files, Git can produce a diff, showing the particular *lines* we changed, or Git can just make a list of the files that we changed.  That's pretty straightforward, but it does mean that to know what *changed* in `H`, Git must extract both snapshots: the one from `H`, but also the one from its parent `G`.

The `git log` command will do this for `H`, then move back one step to `G`.  Now, to see what changed in `G`, Git must compare the snapshot of its parent `F` to the snapshot in `G`.  That suffices for knowing what changed in `G`.

Now `git log` can step backwards yet again.  This repeats as needed, until we have run all the way back to the very first commit, which—by definition—simply *adds* all the files it has in its snapshot.  There's nothing before the root commit `A`, so *everything* is new, and now `git log` can stop.

#### Merges mess with this

That works fine for these simple linear chains, but Git's commits *are not always simple linear chains*.  Suppose we have our simple-so-far repository, where there is only one branch named `main` and it ends at `H`, but now we make some new branch names, make some commits *on* these new branches, and get ready to merge them:

```
          I--J   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- br2
```

Commits up through `H` are on *all* branches, while commits `I-J` are only on `br1` and commits `K-L` are only on `br2`.  Using `git log` at this point shows us `J`, then `I`, then `H`, then `G`, etc., following the arrows backwards from `br1`'s latest commit; or, it shows us `L`, then `K`, then `H`, then `G`, etc., following the arrows backwards from `br2`'s latest commit.

Git will of course find file "changes" in the usual way: compare the snapshot in `L` vs that in `K`, or `K` vs `H`, etc.  Since every commit has exactly one parent commit, this works fine.

Once we *merge*, however, we have a problem.  The merge itself works by:

- comparing `H` vs `J` to see what changed on `br1`;
- comparing `H` vs `L` to see what changed on `br2`; and
- combining these changes, and applying the *combined* changes to the snapshot in `H`.

This keeps "our" changes on `br1` and adds "their" changes on `br2`, if that's the direction we're doing the merge.  Or, it keeps "our" changes on `br2` and adds "their" changes on `br1`.  Either way the result is the same (except for conflict resolutions, if any, which depend on how *we* choose to resolve the conflict).

We now have Git make a new *merge commit*, `M`, which has:

- *one* snapshot, but
- *two* parents.

It looks like this:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M
         \    /
          K--L
```

I have taken the labels away because at this point we often do that: `M` is now the latest `main` commit instead, and when we add another new commit `N` it just extends `main`:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M--N
         \    /
          K--L
```

`N` is an *ordinary single parent commit* as usual, so the niceness of comparing the snapshot in `M` vs that in `N` works as usual, finding the changes as usual.

Merge commit `M`, on the other hand, is quite thorny.  How *should* `git log` show the changes?  *Changes*, in Git, require that we look at "the" parent commit.  But `M` does not have *the* parent.  `M` has *two* parents, `J` and `L`.  Which one should we use?

The `-m` flag means *run two separate `git diff` operations*, one against `J`, and then a second one against `L`.  That way we'll see what changed vs `J`, i.e., what we brought in via `K-L`, and then we'll also see what changed vs `L`, i.e., what we brought in via `I-J`.

Adding `--first-parent` means *follow just one of these lines* so that at `M` we'll see, e.g., what happened in `K-L`, but then *we won't look at `K` or `L` at all any more*.  We'll just move back to `J`.  The *effect* is that Git *pretends*, for the duration of `-m --first-parent`, that the commit graph looks like this:

```
...--G--H--I--J--M--N
```

This is, more or less, literally what you asked for—but it's not what Bitbucket is doing.

#### Undoing the merge mess several other ways

We *can*, if we so choose, have `git log` compare `M` vs both `J` *and* `L`—i.e., make two separate `git diff`s—but then *discard most of the results of these two diffs*.  Git has two different "combined diff" modes, which you can get with `-c` or `--cc`.

Unfortunately, neither one does what you want.  They're also rather difficult to explain (and I still don't really know what the *true* difference between the two is, though they are demonstrably different: I can show some differences, but I don't know what the *goals* are, of the two different options).

#### History Simplification

The real key here though is this.  Suppose there is some file *F* that appears in all three commits `M`, `J`, and `L`.  Remember, this particular snippet of our picture looks like this:

```
       I--J
      /    \
...--H      M
      \    /
       K--L
```

- If *F* is the same in *all three* commits, it's not "interesting" in this merge.  Nobody made *any* changes to it.
- If *F* matches in `J` vs `M`, but is different in `L` vs `M`, then "something interesting" happened.  The same is true if *F* matches in `L` vs `M`, but is different in `J` vs `M`.

What `git log` does in *most cases* here is to try to find out about the *final state* of the file.  Why does file *F* look the way it does in `M`?  But think about this:  **If *F* differs in `J` vs `M` but *matches* in `L` vs `M`, then anything we did to the file along the *top row* is irrelevant!**  We *threw away* the top-row copy of file `F` and kept only the bottom-row copy.

So, if you're asking `git log` *about* file `F` at this point, `git log` simply does not bother to look at commits `I-J`.  It follows only the *bottom* row.

On the other hand, if *F* exactly matches in `J`-vs-`M` but differs in `L`-vs-`M`, `git log -- F` will follow only the *top* row, because we *threw away* anything that came out of the *bottom* row.

This is **History Simplification** in a nutshell.  The `git log` command will, at merge points, *throw out one "side" of the merge entirely* if it can.  If the file(s) we care about *match* one side, that's the side `git log` will pick.  If the file(s) we care about match *all* sides of the merge, `git log` will pick one side at random, and follow that side.

**This means `git log` never even looks at any of the files on the "other side" of the merge** so you will not see any of those commits in the `git log` output.  The program is *assuming* that since the merge took "one side" over the other, that's the *interesting* side, and everything that might show up on the other is irrelevant dross, to be discarded.

#### This is sometimes what you want

The reason `git log` does this kind of history simplification is that it assumes your goal is to know why the file looks the way it does in the *latest* version.  Any irrelevant-dross-commits that got throw out don't matter, so let's not even look at them.

When that's what you want, that's what you want!  But sometimes you want to know: *I'm sure I changed this myself, where was that?* or something similar.  Here, you must tell `git log` *not to do history simplification at all*.  The flag for this is `--full-history`.  There are other history simplification flags, so that you can control the simplification: it is useful after all.  Read through [the `git log` documentation History Simplification section](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_history_simplification) to see them.

It's worth adding one more point here, having to do with so-called *evil merges* (see [Evil merges in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461909/1256452)).  We could have:

```
...--J
      \
       M
      /
...--L
```

where the snapshot files in `M` are *utterly unrelated* to the files in *either* `J` *or* `L`.  More commonly, we might have some file in `M` that has a change hidden away in it that *does not come from* the top or bottom rows at all, but rather was produced due to the fact that there were conflicts and/or the combined changes didn't *work*.

If the "hidden" change is due to conflicts, that's not so bad, but if someone stuck in an *unrelated* fix, we have an issue.  In particular, `git log` by default *does not display merge commits at all* when using `git log -- path`.  It *assumes* that anything interesting that will show up from the `path` argument will be found on either the top or bottom row, in a commit *before* the merge.  But an "evil merge" might introduce an "interesting change" that *isn't* in either row, and this is when you *must* force `git log` to look at merge commits, using `-m`, or `-c`, or `--cc`.

What Bitbucket do with *their* software is of course up to them.  We don't know if they are currently using `--full-history --cc` for instance.  We don't know whether, in future, they might *change* the internal `git log` options.  So there's no real point in trying to make your command-line `git log` output exactly match your Bitbucket view output, as the latter is not under your control in the first place.  If you are going to use `git log`, then, concentrate instead on knowing what `git log` is doing and how to make that work to your advantage.

Comment: Dear @torek, thanks for such a complete answer. I'll comment it in my post...

Comment: Done. Updated the question.

Comment: OK: I'm not at all sure *what* Bitbucket is doing behind the web curtain here, but I suspect they're using `git log --no-merges` (or equivalently, `git log --max-parents=0`, or the same but with `git rev-list` rather than `git log` as they're probably using the plumbing command directly). Whatever *else* they might be using, forcing in the `--no-merges` option drops all the merge commits from being displayed.

Comment: I'll also mention that in your new mini-repo for testing purposes, after you merge `br1` and `br2` into master, the commits along the bottom row *are in `master`*. A `git log` starting from `master` (commit `N`) without `--first-parent` will traverse all the commits. That's what makes a real merge special: after `git merge B`, commits that used to be on `B` but not on the current branch are now on both branches. The new merge commit is only on the current branch though.

Comment: Thanks to your explanation, I did make some steps forward, but I'm still far from understanding the output of the "3 good commands" as they seems to give me false positives.  Though, I clearly owe you the point for the most extensive answer.

Comment: I'll come back to this kind of "wrong results" in a new, separate thread. I'll link it here, for the sake of completeness...

Comment: Follow-up on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69941513/git-file-history-outputs-false-positives

Comment: Dear @torek, what would they be using with `git rev-list`?  Just to remind you, they do show merge commits, but only the right ones... while, in my case, I see other merge commits that are falsely reported as well.

Comment: The reason to run `git rev-list` instead of `git log` is that if you're a computer programmer, you don't want *human readable* output, you want *machine readable* output. That's the core difference between those two commands. (Unfortunately there are a few tricks that `git log` can do that `git rev-list` can't, but for *most* purposes they're equivalent, except that `git log` output is directed at human eyeballs, and `git rev-list` output is directed at other programs.)

Answer (score 1):

> but never shows "merge commits", while the file can have been modified in a branch we did merge into main, for example

If you're going to do this, add `--first-parent -m` (as I see @torek suggests in the comments). Not just `-m`, which by itself is more of a forensic tool for desperation cases only.

What's going on here is, without `--first-parent` Git's already going to show you those changes, in the commit(s) that made them. The merge isn't introducing any *new* changes. If Git showed you the merge diffs, it'd wind up showing you everything at least twice.

This is why it's such a good idea to avoid introducing new work or corrections in a merge commit. The act makes it impossible to reason about what the merge does. Merge conflict detection and resolution is already unbounded. Git does as well as any vcs can, and better than I think every other vcs on the planet, but it can't ever be perfect. Say a value in a list has to have some mathematical relation to a sum of the remaining values, the changes on both branches preserved that relation but when combined, that relation is broken. Or any other such condition: code is added in one branch that depends on an existing compiled-in value, but the other branch makes it user-configurable. Think about that one for a while.

So `--first-parent -m -p` will show you the diffs even for merges, but only changes introduced by the merged branch and conflict resolutions, work done earlier in the mainline will show up in the commits that introduced it.

Comment: Dear @jthill, as you can see in the NEW EXTRA INFORMATION section, no change with *-m* added to the *--first-parent* option... ;-(  I don't see the right commits. Almost nothing in common, if any, with the report from BitBucket.