# Moving file from one repo to another and changing it in parallel

Tags: git, github, repository

I have two repositories: **A** and **B**. File **doc.txt** is located in A repository in **A_master** branch. Current B branch is **B_master**.

I created a branch based on A_master in A repository. I call it **A_feature**. I have also created a branch based on B_master in B repostory, **B_feature**. I commited doc.txt deletion in A_feature. I then commited same doc.txt addition in B_feature. Thus, moved doc.txt from A repository to B repository in *_feature branches. Afterwards, someone changes doc.txt in A_master. I am going to merge A_feature and B_feature.

1. Will I lose doc.txt changes made in A_master? Why?
2. Will I see conflicts in *_feature pull requests? Why?

---

**Edit 1**

... I am going to merge A_feature in A_master and B_feature in B_master.

Answer (score 1):

A Git *repository* is, at its heart, a collection of *commits*.  It's not about files (though commits hold files).  It's not about branches (though branch names help us, and Git, *find* commits).  It's really just a collection of commits.

A *commit*, in Git:

- Is read-only.  No commit can ever be changed!  Not one single bit can be changed.
- Is numbered, with a big ugly *hash ID* expressed in [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal).  The number is unique to that one commit: no other commit, anywhere, in *any* Git repository, can have *that* number.  Any other Git repository that *does* use that number, uses it to hold a copy of *that commit*.
- Contains a snapshot of all of your files (in a special, compressed, Git-only, de-duplicated format) and some metadata.

A *branch name* in Git simply holds the hash ID—the commit number—of one particular commit: the latest one for that branch.  That's all it is, really: a name for one commit.  As you make new commits *in* that branch, Git automatically replaces the stored hash ID with the latest one.

(The metadata within each commit joins them together so that, starting from the latest, Git can work backwards to every previous commit.  So holding the hash ID of the latest commit is sufficient.)

The act of *check out* a commit causes Git to extract all the saved files that are *in* that commit.  The saved files in the commit cannot be changed, and only Git itself is able to *read* them so we have to extract them to use them.  Once extracted *from* Git, those files are not *in Git* any more.  That is, the files you see and work with may have come *out of* a Git repository and a commit, but now they're just ordinary files.

Now that you know the above, you can see where there is an error in your description:

> [I] moved `doc.txt` from **A** repository to **B** repository ...

It's literally impossible to *move* a file from one repository to another:

- Repositories don't hold files; they hold commits.
- Commits can't be changed. "Moving" a file implies that it's gone from one location, and now appears in another.  So this would require changing the files inside some commits, and that's not possible.

You can *copy* a file that you've extracted from some **A**-repository commit into the working tree for your **B*** repository, use `git add` to prepare it to go into a new commit in **B**, and run `git commit` in **B** to add a new commit to **B** in which the file exists.

You can *remove* the file from your working tree in **A** and add the removal (`git add` the removed file, or use `git rm` to do the whole thing in one shot) and then make a new commit in **A**, to add a new commit to **A** in which the file doesn't exist.  The file continues to exist in previous commits in **A**.

> Afterwards, [I made and committed] someone changes [to] `doc.txt` in `A_master`.

This implies you *copied* `doc.txt` into the working tree for **B**, rather than "moving" (copying-and-then-removing) `doc.txt`.  The new additional commits you made in repository **A** hold the updated versions of `doc.txt`.  The previously-existing commits continue to hold the older versions.

> I am going to merge `A_feature` and `B_feature` ...

This may be difficult: `git merge` operates on the *commits in one repository*.  You have two different repositories, **A** and **B**.  If they contain the same *starting* commits—remember, Git is all about the *commits*, as found by their commit numbers—you may be able to load the currently-private-to-**A** commits into repository **B**, or the **B** commits into **A**, and then you may be able to run `git merge` on these commits.

Note that while `git merge` takes a branch name:

```
git checkout br1       # or git switch br1
git merge br2
```

these operations are fundamentally about the *commits* in the repository.  The merge operation, `git merge br2`, uses the *name* `br2` to find the *most recent commit* for that branch.  It then uses the commit metadata from the current commit, and the designated commit, and any predecessor commits as needed, to locate the common starting point commit—the *merge base*—from which the two branch-tips are descended.

If the commits aren't in the same repository, it's impossible to merge them in the first place.

---

#### Edit per "edit 1"

> ... I am going to merge A_feature in A_master and B_feature in B_master.

Let me expand on my own parenthetical comment now:

> (The metadata within each commit joins them together so that, starting from the latest, Git can work backwards to every previous commit. So holding the hash ID of the latest commit is sufficient.)

More specifically, the metadata in a commit includes the raw hash ID of its immediate predecessor commit.  We therefore say that a commit *points to* its *parent*, which we can draw this way:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <--somebranch
```

The branch name `somebranch` here serves to hold the hash ID `H` of the last commit in this chain.  Commit `H` then holds both a snapshot (all files, with each file compressed and de-duplicated against any other copy of the file in this or any other commit) and metadata; the metadata in `H` holds the hash ID of earlier commit `G`.  Commit `G`, being a commit, holds a snapshot and metadata, and its metadata holds the hash ID of earlier commit `F`, and so on.

When you `git checkout` or `git switch` to some branch by name, you check out the commit to which the branch name points.  For instance, if you have:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
```

and you run:

```
git switch master
```

Git will extract, from commit `H`, the snapshot of all files.

When you update some files and `git add` and/or use `git rm`, then run `git commit`, Git will add a *new commit* using the updated-and-added and/or removed files.  This new commit has a full snapshot (based on what you `git add`-ed, plus any files you *didn't* change or remove).  It points backwards to what *was* the *current commit:*

```
...--F--G--H   <-- does anything point here now? (commit I does)
            \
             I   <-- how about here?
```

The tricky bit is that whatever branch name is your *current branch*, as per `git checkout` or `git switch`, Git now writes `I`'s hash ID *into that branch name*:

```
...--F--G--H--I   <-- master
```

Side note: Git makes this new commit's snapshot from whatever is in Git's *index* or *staging area* at this point.  (Index and staging-area are two terms for a single Git thing.)  Using `git add` modifies the index / staging-area, so as to prepare for the next commit.  The files you see and work with in your working tree are there for *you*, not for Git itself: Git works instead with the files stored in its index.  The `git add` command is a way of saying to Git: *Make the index copy of some file(s) match the working tree copy of those files.*

#### Why this matters

In repo **A** you now have two branch names:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master, A_feature
```

You pick one of them to be the *current branch* with `git checkout A_feature`.  To remember which one *is* the current branch, we add the special name `HEAD` to our drawing:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master, A_feature (HEAD)
```

Now you make change(s) to some file(s), `git add` if needed (`git rm` makes the change to both your working tree *and* Git's index, so that no separate `git add` is needed), and commit:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             I   <-- A_feature (HEAD)
```

The change you made was to *remove* `doc.txt`, so the snapshot in new commit `I` has one fewer files in it than the snapshot in commit `H`.

As you make more changes and commit them, you get more commits:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             I--J   <-- A_feature (HEAD)
```

You mention that someone else who has write access to this repository (whoever that might be, and however that might occur) now does a `git checkout master`:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
            \
             I--J   <-- A_feature
```

They now modify `doc.txt`, use `git add`, and run `git commit`:

```
             K   <-- master (HEAD)
            /
...--F--G--H
            \
             I--J   <-- A_feature
```

Commit `K` has the same files as commit `H` except that its copy of `doc.txt` is *different*.

If they make another commit, we get:

```
             K--L   <-- master (HEAD)
            /
...--F--G--H
            \
             I--J   <-- A_feature
```

> I am going to merge A_feature in A_master and B_feature in B_master.

So you will now take this repository, with `HEAD` attached to `master` like this, and run:

```
git merge A_feature
```

The merge operation, in Git, finds two commits to start with:

1. your current commit `L` (via `HEAD` and then `master`);
2. the other commit `J` (via the argument `A_feature`).

It then uses the *graph* that we've been drawing to find the *best shared commit* that's on *both* branches.  In this drawing, that's commit `H`.

Now merge does its real work:

- The merge has to *compare the snapshot in `H` to that in `K` to see what you changed on the current branch*.  According to your description, what changed is, or includes, data within the file named `doc.txt`.
- The merge has to *compare the snapshot in `H` to that in `L` to see what they (whoever they are—it's actually you) changed on the other branch*.  Per your description, the change is, or includes, the *deletion* of the file named `doc.txt`.
- The merge operation must now *combine the changes*.

The usual rules for combining changes within one file are simple and are based purely on text lines.  But in this case, you did not change any *lines* in the `H`-to-`J` diffs.  Instead, you *deleted the entire file*.  This is a "high level" or "tree level" operation.  Meanwhile, they did change some lines in the same file you deleted.

Git is unable to combine these two changes.  It has no rule for resolving this (not even with `-X ours` or `-X theirs`).  You will get a *merge conflict*.  When this happens, Git leaves its index / staging-area in an expanded "conflicted" state.  Git stops the merge in the middle and exits the `git merge` command with a failure status, signifying that something went wrong.

Your job is now to *fix what went wrong*, updating Git's index / staging-area.  You may use the files left in the working tree for this purpose, if you like: Git tries to leave something useful here for you to work with.  But as always for any commit, what really matters to Git are the copies of files that are in its index.

(Side note: to see more directly what's in Git's index, use `git ls-files --stage`.  This produces a huge amount of output in a big repository.  The `git status` command is a more useful way to see what's in Git's index, in a more compact form: Git tells you what's there by *comparing* what's there to what's in the `HEAD` commit, and then also by comparing what's there to what's in your working tree.  Only things that are *different* get mentioned here.  That way, if you have nine thousand files, but only *changed* three of them, you only have to look at three file names, not all 9000.)

As always, once you have the correct file(s) ready, you must use `git add` to have Git update its index.  Adding a conflicted file back "collapses down" the expanded index entries for that file, resolving the merge conflict for that file.  Or, if the correct way to resolve the problem is to *remove* the file, you can use `git rm` to do this.  When you have resolved all the conflicts, you may run `git merge` again to finish the merge:

```
git merge --continue
```

Or, for historical reasons, you can run `git commit` to finish the merge:

```
git commit
```

Git will notice that you've finished resolving the conflicts but are still in the middle of the merge, and will finish the merge either way.  (Using `git merge --continue` currently literally *runs* `git commit`, but first makes sure there is a merge that is ready to finish.  It's therefore somewhat better to use `git merge --continue`, but the old way will be supported or a long time to come, probably forever.)

#### The final result of the merge

Had you *not* gotten a conflict, Git would have made a new merge commit on its own.  Since you *did* get a conflict, you had to resolve it, then finish the merge yourself.  In either case, Git is now ready to make a new commit, in the usual way—mostly.  The new commit has the *current* commit as one of its *two* parents, but instead of just the one parent, it *also* has the *other commit* as its second parent.

The new merge commit `M` still has a single *snapshot*, just like any commit.  This contains (compressed and de-duplicated as usual) a full copy of every file, exactly as you arranged these files in Git's index / staging-area.  But the two parents of `M` are `J` and `L`.  Having written out commit `M`, Git then stores the new commit's hash ID into the branch name as usual, so our picture now looks like this:

```
             K--L
            /    \
...--F--G--H      M   <-- master (HEAD)
            \    /
             I--J   <-- A_feature
```

The merge operation is now complete.  The *snapshot* for `M` is *whatever you put in it* (because `git merge` stopped with a conflict, which gave you an opportunity to put *any files you like* into it).<sup>1</sup>  The *first parent* of `M` is `L`, which is the commit that *was* the `HEAD` commit when you started; now the `HEAD` commit is commit `M`, of course.  The *second parent* of `M` is `J`, the commit you named on your `git merge` command.

---

<sup>1</sup>Note that if you're going to make an unconflicted merge, `git merge other` will make that commit on its own, and the files *in* that snapshot are the result of the automatic merge that Git made between the two branch tip commits based on the merge base.  However, you *can* run `git merge --no-commit`: this places the merge result into the index / staging-area as usual, but then stops even though there was no merge conflict.  You may now complete the merge later with `git commit` or `git merge --continue`, as if there had been a conflict—but you can also modify what's in the staging area as usual.

This gives you the opportunity to create an [evil merge](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461909/1256452).  See the link for what this is and why you should not abuse this ability.

---

#### What happens in repo B

I leave this as an exercise.  Draw the graph with the various names pointing to the various commits.  Add new commits, making note of what's different in the various snapshots you make.  Then think about how `git merge` will run the two `git diff` commands: find the merge base commit, and see what changed since that snapshot, in each of the two branch-tip commits.  Consider how Git will try to combine those changes.  Are there conflicts?  Are they whole-file / tree-level / high-level conflicts?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback and great answer. I have corrected my question so that it would fit my requirements: 

... I am going to merge A_feature in A_master and B_feature in B_master.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, branches A_feature and B_feature are in different repositories so they can't be merged with each other. So this scenario can't happen.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I fixed my question. 

I am going to merge A_feature in A_master and B_feature in B_master.