# Difference between merging develop into master and master into develop?

Tags: git

Difference between merging develop into master and master into develop? I tried to merge develop into master and it gave me 34 files and 1,312 additions and 324 removals and I tried to merge master into develop and it gave me 251 files and 87,123 additions and 1,321 removals. My guess is that it takes the time it spun off from master and then take all the changes and compared it with the files changed on that branch from the files in the branch we want to merge into? Am I correct?

It means that for both branches to be the same, we need to merge master into develop and then merge develop into master every time when both branches were being changed on a daily basis for 1 month + by a dozen of developers?

What does git-diff give us? Does it give us all the differences from both branches or what we would get if we tried to merge branch 1 into branch 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand the answer to that question, let's start with some facts about Git:

- Git stores *commits*, rather than files or branches.  The commits *are* the history in a repository: each one has a unique number (a *hash ID* or *object ID* aka OID), and each one holds two things: a full snapshot of every file, plus some metadata.  The metadata in any one commit includes a list of previous commit hash IDs, which lets Git relate the later commits back to earlier ones.  Most (all "ordinary") commits have just one previous hash ID in them, which links the commit to its parent.  This allows Git to work backwards, from the latest commit to the earliest.
- Branch names like `master` or `main`, `develop`, `br1`, `feature/tall`, etc., just contain *one* commit hash ID.  By definition, whatever hash ID is stored in the name is the *latest* commit on that branch.

From these two facts alone we can start to visualize commits:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <--br1
```

Here we have a branch name like `br1` that selects, or *points to*, the *last* commit that is on that branch.  That commit has some hash ID that we'll just call `H` so that we don't have to generate some random looking thing and try to remember it.

Commit `H` holds a snapshot of all files, but also holds metadata to say who *made* commit `H`, why (their log message), and so on.  The metadata for commit `H` stores the hash ID of one previous commit, which we'll just call `G`.  So commit `H` points backwards to earlier commit `G`.

Commit `G`, being a commit, stores a full snapshot, and metadata.  The metadata in `G` make `G` point backwards to earlier commit `F`, which is also a commit, so it points backwards to another earlier commit.

When we *look at* a commit with `git diff` or `git show`, we're actually giving Git *two* commit hash IDs.  We start with the commit itself, such as `H`, maybe using the branch name `br1`:

```
git show br1
```

Git uses that to locate `H`, then uses `H` to locate its parent commit `G`.  Git then extracts, to a temporary area in memory, *both* snapshots, and compares them.  We are, after all, interested only in the files that *changed*.  (This is assisted by the fact that commit snapshots *de-duplicate* file contents, so if `H` and `G` mostly share most of the files, Git can tell that instantly and not even bother extracting those files.)

For files that *did* change, Git figures out a "change recipe"—a *diff*—and shows that as "what happened".  This works great for ordinary commits like commit `H`.  But it breaks down with merges.

#### Merges

To understand `git merge`, we start with the *goal* of a merge: *to combine work*.  Let's draw a picture of some commits where there's been a fork of some sort, so that we have *two different chains of work*, like this:

```
          I--J   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- br2
```

That is, there are at this point *two* "latest" commits.  Commit `J` is latest; and its parent is `I`, whose parent is `H`, whose parent is `G` and so on.  But commit `L` is *also* latest; its parent is `K`, whose parent is `H`, whose parent is `G` and so on.  Here `J` is the latest *`br1` commit* and `L` is the latest *`br2` commit*.

As always, every commit holds a full snapshot of all files.  To combine *work* on both branches, we need to find *changes*.  How do we do that?  Well, we already know an answer: we can use `git diff` or `git show` to pick two commits and *compare* them.

The thing everyone tries first—which doesn't work—is to pick commits `J` and `L` and compare them.  But that shows what's different between these two "latest"s, which usually isn't what we want.  For instance, maybe Alice made `br1` by fixing a typo in the README and adding feature 1, and Bob made `br2` by fixing a different typo in some other documentation and adding feature 2.  If we diff `J` vs `L`, the recipe Git will give us is: *remove the fix and feature from Alice, and add the fix and feature from Bob*.  What we *want* is *add the fix and feature from Alice, and also add the fix and feature from Bob*.

To cut to the chase, the trick here is to start from commit `H`.  That's the best *shared* commit: a commit that is literally on both branches.  By starting at `J` and working backwards and *also* starting at `L` and working backwards, we find that `H` is the best *shared* commit.  So we diff `H` vs `J` to see what Alice did, and then—separately!—diff `H` vs `L` to see what Bob did.  *That* gets us the sets of changes to combine.

Git will then do its best to combine these change-recipes, using some very simple rules:

- If nobody touched a file, use any version of it: all three are the same.
- If one branch touches some file and the other branch doesn't touch it at all, use the changed file from the one branch that changed it.
- If both touched some file, try to combine the changes, line-by-line.  If they're on *different, non-overlapping* lines, they can be combined.  Git adds the rule that the lines must not [abut](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/abut) either.  If they do overlap, they must be 100% identical.  Otherwise, Git will declare a *merge conflict* and make you, the programmer, clean up the mess.

These rules work surprisingly often, so that `git merge` can get both sets of changes out of the two branches, apply the *combined* changes to the snapshot in `H`, and use that for a new snapshot.  Depending on how you like to view this, the result is that we keep the `br1` changes while adding the `br2` changes, or we keep the `br2` changes while adding the `br1` changes.  Note that, like ordinary mathematical addition, the result is the same regardless of the order of the [addends](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Addend.html) (that is, we don't need to define a separate "augend" vs "addend" because the operation is [commutative](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Commutative.html)).<sup>1</sup>

Having come up with a *snapshot* for the new commit, Git then *makes* the new commit.  You supply a log message in which you explain why you did the merge—or you use the crappy default message, `merge branch br2` for instance, which is what most people really do—and Git makes a new commit that is just like any commit: it has a snapshot and metadata.  What makes the new commit special is that instead of just *one* parent, it has *two:*

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M
         \    /
          K--L
```

Note that I have filed the branch names off this picture.  Whenever you make *any* new commit—whether with `git commit`, or `git merge`, or `git cherry-pick` or `git revert` or whatever—Git will update the *current branch name* automatically for you, so that `M` is now the latest commit.  But which branch *name* gets updated?  Well, that depends on which branch name `git status` said you were `on`:

```
$ git status
On branch `br1`
...
$ git merge br2
```

results in:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   <-- br2
```

That is, you were "on" `br1`—that's what the `HEAD` attached to `br1` means here—and you still are, so the new commit is also the latest for `br1`.  But if `git status` said that you were `On branch br2` and you had run `git merge br1`, it would be the name `br2` that is updated.

---

<sup>1</sup>Note that adding *options* to `git merge`, such as `-s ours` or `-X theirs` for instance, changes this: the operation is no longer commutative.

---

#### This answers the first part of your question

> [What is the d]ifference between merging develop into master and master into develop?

One will advance the name `master`, and the other will advance the name `develop`.  That is, you'll have either:

```
       o--...--o
      /         \
...--o           M   <-- master (HEAD)
      \         /
       o--...--o   <-- develop
```

or:

```
       o--...--o   <-- master (HEAD)
      /         \
...--o           M   <-- develop (HEAD)
      \         /
       o--...--o
```

when you're done.  The *snapshot* in `M` will be the same either way.

#### The rest is either unimportant or crucial

Since the *commits* are what matter, the *name* you use to access the result of the merge is not very important.  Well, except for one thing: if you *keep using* that name to make *more* commits, and want to access these "more commits", the name you had Git advance is absolutely critical.

That is:

```
       o--...--o
      /         \
...--o           M--N   <-- master (HEAD)
      \         /
       o--...--o   <-- develop
```

and:

```
       o--...--o
      /         \
...--o           M   <-- master (HEAD)
      \         /
       o--...--o--N   <-- develop
```

are entirely different pictures.  That's because we make a *new* commit by starting with the snapshot from some existing commit, changing a few things, and committing the result.  So what's in `N`'s snapshot will depend on whether you started from commit `M`—the merge result—or not.

But note that we can *rename* the two branches any time:

```
       o--...--o
      /         \
...--o           M   <-- smorgas (HEAD)
      \         /
       o--...--o   <-- bord
```

It's not the *names* that matter, it's the commits.  So you should arrange the *commits* the way you want, and use names that help you achieve your goals.  To do that properly, you'll need a good mental grasp of what your goals actually *are* in the first place.  All that matters to Git are the *commits;* the *branch names* are just ways that Git helps you find the right OIDs, so that you can find the commits you care about.

#### The rest of it

> I tried to merge develop into master and it gave me 34 files and 1,312 additions and 324 removals and I tried to merge master into develop and it gave me 251 files and 87,123 additions and 1,321 removals.

Any time Git says "*A* files added, *R* files removed, *C* files changed" (plus the number of lines added or removed to/from the changed files), Git has run `git diff`.  When we have this:

```
...--F--G--H--I--J
```

and we're using commit `H` with `git show`, it's simple enough here: Git is comparing commit `G`, the parent of `H`, with commit `H`, to get that set of numbers.  But when we have:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   <-- br2
```

and Git is trying to tell us something about commit `M`, well, `M` has *two* parents, not just one.  So which one did Git use in the `git diff` it ran to come up with the numbers?

The answer here is that Git uses the *first* parent of the merge.  When you run:

```
git switch somebranch
git merge otherbranch
```

and get a new merge commit that goes *on* `somebranch`, its *first* parent is the commit that *was* at the tip of `somebranch` just a moment ago, and its *second* parent is the commit that *is* (still) at the tip of `otherbranch`.  So you'll get different numbers here if we switch to `br2` and merge `br1`.  If we add the parent numbers to the diagram, we can show how this works visually:

```
          I--J
         /    \₁
...--G--H      M   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         \    /²
          K--L   <-- br2
```

vs:

```
          I--J   <-- br1
         /    \²
...--G--H      M   <-- br2 (HEAD)
         \    /₁
          K--L
```

So you'll see different *statistics* even though the *snapshot* in `M` is the same either way, because Git is comparing `M` vs either `J` or vs `L`.

> It means that for both branches to be the same, we need to merge master into develop and then merge develop into master every time ...

You *can* do this, but watch out!  Not every `git merge` actually makes a *merge commit*.  If you force `git merge` to make a merge commit, and you start with:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   <-- br2
```

and run `git switch br2 && git merge --no-ff br1`, you get this:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- br1
         \    / \
          K--L---N   <-- br2 (HEAD)
```

where the first parent of `N` is `L` and the second parent of `N` is `M`.  Commits `M` and `N` will (generally<sup>2</sup>) have the same *snapshot*, but they have different numbers and are different commits.

But `git merge` doesn't always make a merge commit.  Consider the following branch structure:

```
...--G--H   <-- main (HEAD)
         \
          I--J   <-- feature
```

Here we used two commits to develop a new feature.  We're now ready to merge it.  If we run `git merge feature`, a true merge would have to:

- find the merge base: that's commit `H`;
- diff the snapshot in `H` against our current snapshot `H` to see what we changed, **but that's obviously nothing at all** because `H` *is* `H`;
- diff the snapshot in `H` against their snapshot in `J` to see what they changed;
- add the non-changed stuff in ours to the changed stuff in theirs and apply those changes to what's in `H`, giving their snapshot; and
- make a new merge commit.

The result looks like this:

```
...--G--H------M   <-- main (HEAD)
         \    /
          I--J   <-- feature
```

and the snapshot in `M` matches that in `J`.  But Git takes a shortcut.  It says to itself: *Well, duh, if I diff commit `H` against itself, that's obviously empty.  The merge result will have the snapshot from `J`.  What if I just use commit `J`?*  If you allow it to do so, `git merge` will then *use commit J*, giving:

```
...--G--H
         \
          I--J   <-- feature, main (HEAD)
```

after which there's no reason to bother with the kink in the drawing:

```
...--G--H--I--J   <-- feature, main (HEAD)
```

If you let Git do it, this is the kind of merge you'll get if you switch to `develop` and `git merge master`:

```
       o--...--o
      /         \
...--o           M   <-- develop (HEAD), master
      \         /
       o--...--o
```

There's now just the one commit `M` that is the latest on *both branches*.

If you now make a new commit *on* `develop` at this point, you get:

```
       o--...--o
      /         \
...--o           M   <-- master
      \         / \
       o--...--o   N   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

Note how the parent of commit `N` is commit `M`: it is an ordinary single-parent non-merge commit.  This it the same thing that you get if you first *delete* the name `develop` while you have this:

```
       o--...--o
      /         \
...--o           M   <-- master (HEAD)
      \         /
       o--...--o   [the name develop *was* here, but now is deleted]
```

then create a *new* `develop` from commit `M` with:

```
git branch develop    # or git switch -c develop
```

so that the new name points to commit `M`.

Some web hosting sites (e.g., GitHub) won't let you do a fast-forward not-really-a-merge operation through their web interface.  For these sites, you must use command-line Git, or delete and re-create branch names, to get this particular effect *if you want it*.  When and whether you want it is your choice though!

---

<sup>2</sup>You can defeat this in many ways, including both options and the so-called [evil merge](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461909/1256452).

---

#### Conclusion

You need to know what Git actually does *and* what you want.  People come up with all kinds of fancy branching models for Git, but just picking one and following it without understanding *why* someone *chose* that model could get you into trouble.  The point of a branch name, in Git, is to *automatically find the latest commit* using a human-readable name, and because humans do this, you need to understand what the humans are thinking; *this*, not Git itself, is what makes this truly hard.