# How to squash merge commits and normal commits with git rebase -i --rebase-merges command

Tags: git, merge, rebase, squash

I am working with a relatively big main branch. I create feature branches and merge them into the main branch. Most of such feature branches are orphan branches. Sometimes, I merge one upper-level main branch into a lower-level main branch (PROD to UAT) to align them together.

When doing `git pull` sometimes I forget to use the`--rebase` option, and I end up seeing annoying merge commits. I want to remove them.

Please see the attached snapshot for this command TODO:

```
git rebase -i -rebase-merges HEAD~4
```

I have the following questions:

- Why did when I used this command instead `git rebase -i -rebase-merges HEAD~3`, the TODO file became much smaller and only 3 or 4 items showed up in the file?
- Not sure what I did exactly, when I tried to squash a normal commit which was just before a merge commit, the merge commit disappeared and the feature branch that was merged also was removed from the history. Can you explain what happened? I remember the process stopped, I had to resolve some conflicts, and do a commit, then continue the rebase.
- How I can squash the indicated merge commits into one normal commit or merge commit?
- How to squash the indicated merge commits into a previous normal commit?
- I want to understand more about the lines starting with `reset` and `label`. Can you give some details or point me to a link to do more reading?

I appreciate your help.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## Part 2 ([link to part 1 here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73466611/1256452))

#### Rebasing with merges, with or without `--rebase-merges`

Suppose that instead of a simple:

```
...--o--*--P  <-- main
         \
          F--G--H   <-- feature (HEAD)
```

style branch setup at the start, we have this:

```
...--o--*--P  <-- main
         \
          \         I--J
           \       /    \
            F--G--H      M--N   <-- feature (HEAD)
                   \    /
                    K--L
```

That is, we have some branch-and-merge kind of thing happening *in* our `feature` branch.  We now want to rebase `feature` onto commit `P`, as if we started our work there instead of at commit `*`.

A plain `git rebase main` will:

- paint `P` and `*` red; and
- paint `N` and `M` and `J`-and-`L` and `I`-and-`K` and `H` and `G` and `F` green

and those would be our commits-to-be-copied.  But *regular* rebase *drops* merge commits like `M` entirely, *on purpose*.  The reason for this is that `git cherry-pick` literally cannot copy a merge commit like `M`.  This "drop merges" happens in the same way as "drop commits that are copies" (except that it's much easier internally).  We end up with:

```
             F'-G'-H'-I'-J'-K'-L'-N'   <-- feature (HEAD)
            /
...--o--*--P  <-- main
         \
          \         I--J
           \       /    \
            F--G--H      M--N   [abandoned]
                   \    /
                    K--L
```

or, perhaps, the `I-J` and `K-L` order get switched around so that we have `F'-G'-H'-K'-L'-I'-J'-N'`.

**The final snapshot in `N'` is just as good as the final snapshot in `N` was** and the reason for this is that the merge commit `M` simply *combined the work* of `I-J` and `K-L`.  When we used cherry-pick to copy each commit, one at a time, and *flatten* the merge away, we *still got the same changes*.  **The fact that `M` is not an evil merge means that it was *safe to omit it*.**

This obviously breaks if `M` is an evil merge.  So perhaps evil merges are bad!  That's why I said above that it's possible **but usually a bad idea** to squash an ordinary commit into a merge.  The result is an evil merge and it gets dropped by this kind of `git rebase`.

What about `--rebase-merges`?  Well, in this case, you get a much more complicated `TODO` worksheet:

> I want to understand more about the lines starting with `reset` and `label`. Can you give some details or point me to a link to do more reading?

What `git rebase` needs to do here is *re-create* merge commit `M`.  The cherry-pick command still can't copy it, so instead of copying it, Git has to *re-perform* the merge.

The instruction sheet will now say:

- copy commits `F`, `G`, and `H`: three `pick` commands
- save the hash ID of commit `H'`: one `label`
- copy commits `I` and `J` now, and save the hash ID of commit `J'`, or copy `K` and `L` now and save `L'`: one more `label`
- switch back to commit `H` using the first label
- copy the other two commits that we didn't copy yet
- some more stuff, but let's pause at this point to draw what we have.

At this point in our copying-commits-to-new-and-improved-commits process, we have this:

```
                       I'-J'  [labeled and possibly HEAD]
                      /
               F'-G'-H'  [labeled]
              /       \
             /         K'-L'  [labeled and possibly HEAD]
            /
...--o--*--P  <-- main
         \
          \         I--J
           \       /    \
            F--G--H      M--N   <-- feature
                   \    /
                    K--L
```

We had to `label` commit `H'` so that we could `reset` to it.  We had to `label` at least one of commits `J'` and `L'` so that we could find it again—whichever isn't `HEAD`.  It's easier to just label both, and there's a reason to do that anyway, as we're about to see.

We're now ready to make `M'`, our "copy" of `M`.  We can't use cherry-pick at all; we have to run `git merge`.  We'd like it to re-use the *commit message* from commit `M`, so we get a `merge -C <hash> <label>`, where the hash ID is that of the original merge, and the label is the commit we want merged in.  Since the *order* of the two commits matters, we may need start with a `reset` to make sure `HEAD` selects commit `J'` now, if we're on `L'`.  If we do, we need a label *for* `J'` to reset to.  We don't know what the hash ID of `J'` will be at the time we generate the `TODO` list.

Anyway, we now reset to the appropriate first commit, and `git merge` the second one, to produce `M'`.  Then we're ready to cherry-pick `N'` and that's the last operation before the rebase can finish on its own by moving the name `feature`:

```
                       I'-J'
                      /    \
               F'-G'-H'     M'-N'  <-- feature (HEAD)
              /       \    /
             /         K'-L'
            /
...--o--*--P  <-- main
         \
          \         I--J
           \       /    \
            F--G--H      M--N   [abandoned]
                   \    /
                    K--L
```

Note that the `git merge` that builds commit `M` does a *new merge*.  **Again, this is safe because—or more precisely, *if*—commit `M` is not an evil merge.**  So `--rebase-merges` doesn't save us from the error of making an evil merge.

#### Getting back to your first question

We can now finally also answer this:

> Why did when I used this command instead `git rebase -i --rebase-merges HEAD~3`, the TODO file became much smaller and only 3 or 4 items showed up in the file?

The red-and-green-paint trick determines which commits are to be copied.  This doesn't depend on the `--rebase-merges` flag, which—as we saw above—just selects whether Git should *re-perform* merges, or *flatten them away*.

It really sounds like you want to *flatten away* your merges.  To do that, *don't use `--rebase-merges`*.  However, note that the red/green-paint thing can get tricky.  In particular, `git rebase` only lets you pick *one* commit to select-with-history, to apply "red paint" from there on back.

You will *always* get the "green paint" applied to whichever commit is `HEAD` when you run `git rebase`, plus other commits selected because of the "with history" style selection.<sup>4</sup>  Remember that the commits *are* the history, and a `git merge` that you did in the past *becomes* a *branch* when we scan backwards, the way Git does.

---

<sup>4</sup>Caveat: if you run `git rebase --onto X Y Z` or `git rebase Y Z`, the operation start with a `git switch Z`, and *that's* the commit that `HEAD` selects.  This is *exactly equivalent* to running `git switch Z` *first*, and then running `git rebase --onto X Y` or `git rebase Y`, including the fact that when the rebase completes, you're "on" branch `Z`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I want to give bounties for this how? In the meantime, I have some questions to be able to understand a lot of what you have written. I am going to post the questions here and answer them when you can.

Answer (score 1):

To set `--rebase` by default for `git pull`:

```
git config --global pull.rebase true
```

---

To view your history: use `git log --graph --oneline`

You can compare :

```
git log --graph --oneline HEAD~3..HEAD
# and
git log --graph --oneline HEAD~4..HEAD
```

(those are the commits selected by both your `git rebase` commands)

Answer (score 1):

## Part 1 ([link to part 2 here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73466726/1256452))

You cannot squash a merge commit.  There's a simple reason for this: a merge commit is, by definition, a commit with *two* parents.  Squashing two commits together means that you'd like to replace two *ordinary* (i.e., single-parent) commits with one ordinary commit.  As a merge commit is not an ordinary commit, it's simply not eligible for squashing.

As a rather special case, it is possible—but usually a bad idea—to squash an ordinary commit into a merge commit.  This produces what is known as an *evil merge:* see [Evil merges in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461909/1256452)

> Why did when I used this command instead `git rebase -i -rebase-merges HEAD~3`, the TODO file became much smaller and only 3 or 4 items showed up in the file?

Rebase is about *copying* commits to new and improved (or at least, presumably-improved) commits.  Having copied those commits, you then direct your Git software to *stop using the originals* and start using the copies instead.

Only ordinary commits can be copied this way.  However, there is a new-ish `--rebase-merges` option (side note: the double hyphen here is required; you can use `-r` as a synonym to avoid having to type a double hyphen), first available in Git 2.22, with numerous fixes and improvements in later versions.  This tells Git to *re-perform* the specified merges.  To *get rid of* merges, you want to avoid performing them at all.  This requires detailed understanding of how rebase works.

The argument you're using here, `HEAD~3` or `HEAD~4`, specifies *which commits not to copy*.  Without this information Git would have to assume that you mean to copy *every reachable commit* (`git rev-list --count HEAD` would tell you how many commits that is, but it's probably hundreds or thousands).  This argument is required unless you use `--root` to tell Git that it should copy every reachable commit (usually a bad idea, which is why `rebase --root` was not in Git for many years, until 1.7.12 was released in 2012).

#### Understanding commits

Getting all of this stuff into your head is a pretty big commitment (if I may use the word *commit* here).  Still, it's important to do it.  Remember that a repository itself is primarily a big box full of commits, so it's very important to know what each commit is and how they work, individually *and* together.  More precisely, the two fundamental components of any Git repository are an *objects database*, which holds commit objects and other supporting objects, and a *names database*, which holds branch and tag and other names.

We start here with the objects, most specifically the commits.  (The other three object types—tree, blob, and annotated-tag—are not in your face the way commits are: they mostly just work and you don't have to know the details, the way you do for commits).  Every Git object is *numbered*, with a big ugly random-looking *hash ID*, or more formally an *object ID* or OID.  These objects IDs can often be abbreviated, e.g., to the `4d3abd9` that appears in your image, but each one is actually 40 characters long (20 bytes or 160 bits), at least today.  (Future versions of Git will someday have 256-bit = 64 character OIDs.)

For commits in particular, each commit gets a *unique* hash ID, at the time you (or whoever) make the commit.  That one hash ID is now reserved forever, in *every* Git repository, even ones that do not yet exist, to mean *that particular commit*.  This literally cannot work forever, and someday Git will break, but the sheer size of the hash ID is intended to put that day so far into the future (billions of years or more) that we don't care about this.  To make this work as well as it does—which in practice, is just fine, even though it's theoretically rubbish—*no part of any object can ever be changed*.  The trick by which Git ensures that other Gits that have never seen your new commit yet, and have no communications link *to* your repository, have already reserved that hash ID, is to use a cryptographic checksum of the commit content, and that trick only works if the content cannot be changed.<sup>1</sup>  That's currently the SHA-1 hash.

So: a commit is a numbered entity, found in Git's objects database—a simple [key-value store](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key%E2%80%93value_database) with a hash ID as the key—by looking up its hash ID.  Git *desperately needs* the hash ID to *find* the commit.  Without that hash ID, Git is helpless.  That's why you keep seeing them.

But what's *in* a commit?  What good is a commit?  The answer is simple, and two-fold:

- A commit stores (indirectly) a *full snapshot of every file*.  More precisely, it stores a full snapshot of every file Git was told to store, at the time you, or whoever, made the commit.  As with all objects, this snapshot is completely read-only.  For multiple purposes, the files are stored in a special form in which their content is compressed and *de-duplicated*.  The de-duplication takes care of the obvious objection, that if every commit stores every file every time, the repository will become hugely bloated.  As long as most commits mostly re-use most of the files from one or more *previous* commits, those files take literally no space at all, because they're de-duplicated away.
- A commit also stores (directly) some *metadata*, or information about the commit itself.  This is the only part of a commit that *must* occupy some space, and it's pretty tiny: it holds the name and email address of the person who made the commit, for instance, and some date-and-time-stamps and the log message.  If your log message is not crazy long, the uncompressed commit is probably no more than a few hundred bytes (and then it gets compressed too).

Crucially for Git itself, the metadata for any given commit *also* stores a list of hash IDs.  This list is usually just one entry long, which makes this commit an *ordinary* commit, with a single parent.  The hash ID stored *in* the commit, in its metadata, is the hash ID of the *parent* of this commit, i.e., the commit that comes just before this one.

At least one commit in any non-empty repository is special because it has *no* parent: it's the *first commit* and it therefore is a *root commit* instead of an ordinary commit.  It still has a full snapshot, just like any commit.  It's possible to make extra root commits, using `git checkout --orphan` or `git switch --orphan`, but that's *usually a bad idea*.  (You mentioned that you are using "orphan branches", and that's usually a bad idea, as we'll see.)

Some commits have *more than one parent*, which makes them *merge commits*.  A merge commit still has just the single snapshot, like any other commit.  Most merge commits have exactly two parents—some version control systems require this (e.g., Mercurial) but since Git has a *list* of parents, Git allows any integer ≥ 2 here.  A multi-parent merge does not do anything that a two-parent merge couldn't do—in fact, it's kind of the reverse: a two-parent merge can do things that a 3+-parent merge can't.  So they can be used for tying together multiple features.  In my own opinion, though, they're mostly for showing off.

---

<sup>1</sup>The observant student, or anyone who knows Mercurial, can immediately note that it works if there's some unchanging *portion* of the content: if we have some changeable part that's not included in the checksum, we're fine.  Git doesn't bother implementing this though, on the theory that any such content could be put somewhere else (which is always true but not always efficient, but [as Kilgore Trout might say, so it goes](https://www.theguardian.com/books/2007/apr/15/fiction.kurtvonnegut)).

---

#### Relating a commit to an earlier commit: links in a chain

Let's pause now and draw an ordinary commit.  We don't know (nor want to know) its actual hash ID; let's just call it `H` for "hash":

```
            <-H
```

What's this little arrow sticking out of `H`?  It's to *represent* the hash ID stored in the commit's metadata.  This hash ID allows Git to retrieve `H`'s *parent* from the objects database.  Let's draw in the parent:

```
        <-G <-H
```

We say that `H` *points to* its parent `G`.  But there's an arrow coming out of `G` too, because like `H`, `G` is an ordinary commit, so `G` points backwards to *its* parent:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

This goes on forever—or rather, until we reach a *root* commit (probably *the* root commit), which lacks the arrow.  That's where we, and Git, get to stop and rest.

There is one problem here, which is that we have to tell Git the hash ID of commit `H`.  Nobody wants to memorize hash IDs, and type them in, so there's one more arrow, and it's one I'll almost always draw.  I get lazy about the ones from commit back to parent:

```
...--F--G--H   <--
```

I'll show what's on the right of that final arrow in a moment.  For now, let's observe:  **Naming commit `H` implicitly names *every commit leading up to and including* commit `H`.**  More precisely, Git has two ways to look up a commit: "with history", which means *drag in previous commits too*, or "without history", which means we should follow some arrow once to find one commit.  When we use the "with history" variety of looking things up, this drags in lots of commits, by following arrows backwards until we either run out of commits (by reaching the root) or by hitting a place we're told to stop.

#### Branch names find the last commit: how branches grow

Now we fill in the part to the right of that last arrow:

```
...--G--H   <-- main
```

What goes on the right is the *branch name*, or in many cases, *branch names and other names too*.  We can have more than one name that selects commit `H` like this:

```
...--G--H   <-- feature, main
```

Whenever a branch name points to any one particular commit—as in this case, where both names `feature` and `main` point to `H`—we say that this particular commit is the *tip commit* of that branch.  So commit `H` is the *tip* of *both* branches, `feature` and `main`.

When we want to use Git, we'll *check out* (or `git switch` to) one of these branch names.  We can only use one branch name at a time,<sup>2</sup> for reasons I won't cover here as this will already be too long, but we'll draw that by attaching the special name `HEAD` and attaching it to one of the branch names:

```
...--G--H   <-- feature, main (HEAD)
```

Here, we are *using commit `H`* because we're selecting one commit, without history, through the name `main`.  If we run `git switch feature` or `git checkout feature`—these do the same thing—we get:

```
...--G--H   <-- feature (HEAD), main
```

Now we're using commit `H`—i.e., we haven't changed anything at all about the *commit* we're using—but we're doing so through the *name* `feature`.

If we now make one new commit, our *new* commit will:

- save a full snapshot of every file (de-duplicated) as those files appear in Git's *index* / *staging area* (which we won't cover here); and
- have Git put our commit message and other metadata together to make a new commit, that gets a new, unique, never-before-used, never-to-be-used-again hash ID that we'll just call `I`.

This new commit `I` will necessarily have commit `H` as its parent, because that's the commit we're using *when* we make new commit `I`.  So `I` will point back to `H`:

```
...--G--H
         \
          I
```

But what about the branch names and *their* arrows?  Well, the *name* `main` contains the raw hash ID of existing commit `H`, and that has not changed.  But we're *on* branch `feature`, so the last step of `git commit` is to write the new hash ID—the raw hash ID for commit `I`—*into the name `feature`*, so that `feature` now points to `I` instead of `H`:

```
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          I   <-- feature (HEAD)
```

The special name `HEAD` is still attached to `feature`, but `feature` now points to `I` as its tip commit.  Commits up through `H` are still on *both branches*, but commit `I` is currently *only on `feature`*.

---

<sup>2</sup>Since Git 2.5, you can use `git worktree add` to add extra working trees: each one can be on one branch.  For various reasons, each added work-tree must be on a *different branch* from all other work-trees, but this is a very good way to deal with multiple branches when, for instance, you need to fix a high-priority bug without also losing momentum with some feature you're in the middle of.

---

#### Commits cannot change but branch names can and do

Note how the only thing we've done to the *commits* here is to add new ones.  That's literally *all* we can do: we cannot remove existing commits, and we cannot change existing commits.  If there is something we don't like about some commit, all we can do is add another commit.  That's the nature of commits: that's how Git can work at all.  Commits never change; once you give one to some other Git repository, that repository has *that* commit, under *that hash ID* that all Git software in the universe agrees is reserved to *that commit*, and now they have it too.

Branch names, however, can and do move all the time.  A branch name, which is just a special kind of name stored in the repository's *names* database—a branch name is just a string prefixed with `refs/heads/`, which is what makes it a branch name—stores *exactly one hash ID*, as do *all* names in this names database.  **Whatever hash ID is in that branch name is the last commit on that branch.**  That's a literal definition in Git.

So, if we have:

```
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          I   <-- feature (HEAD)
```

in our repository, and we force Git to move the name `main` to point to `G` instead of `H`, we get:

```
...--G   <-- main
      \
       H--I   <-- feature (HEAD)
```

Now commits up through and including `G` are on both branches.  Commit `G` is the tip commit of `main`.  Commits `H-I` are on branch `feature`.  **Nothing has changed in the commits themselves.**  The branch names literally don't matter, *except* that we use them to *find the last commit* of each branch.

Should we move the name `main` *forward* instead of *backwards*, we get:

```
...--G--H--I   <-- feature (HEAD), main
```

and now all commits are on both branches.  *The set of branches that contain any given commit changes over time.*  The commits themselves do not change, but the names by which we can *find* the commits *do* change.

If we like, we could force the name `feature` back one hop, leaving `main` at `H`:

```
...--G--H   <-- feature (HEAD), main
         \
          I   ???
```

Commit `I` remains in the repository, but unless you have memorized its hash ID—or can find it somehow—you can't *get to it any more*.  Remember that Git *needs* the hash ID to find something in its objects database.  There's no *forwards* arrow from `H` to `I`, only a backwards one from `I` to `H`, and a backwards one from `H` to `G` and so on.  All Git operations require that we know where we *end;* Git works backwards, so we start with the end.  (The last shall be first, perhaps? )

#### But we can *copy* commits to new-and-improved commits

Suppose we have this as before:

```
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          I   <-- feature (HEAD)
```

and we discover something bad about commit `I`.  Maybe a file has a typo.  Maybe the commit message has a typo.  Maybe both are true.  Whatever is the case, we fix anything about any files and `git add` them so that we can redo the commit, then we run:

```
git commit --amend
```

This does not change existing commit `I`: it literally can't.  Instead, it makes a new and improved commit that's a lot like `I`—maybe it has the same snapshot, if there wasn't anything wrong with the *files*—with slightly different metadata (maybe we've fixed a typo in the commit message; in any case, the committer time stamp is "now" and time has moved on since we made `I`).  So we get our new commit `I'`, which is a lot like `I`, and Git shoves `I'`'s hash ID into the name `feature`.  What `--amend` does is make `git commit` store, as `I'`'s parent, the parent that `I` has, i.e., the hash ID of commit `H`, instead of using `I` itself as the parent.  So now we have this:

```
          I'  <-- feature (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          I   ???
```

Commit `I` seems to have vanished.  If we aren't vigilant about commit hash IDs, commit `I'` seems to *be* commit `I`, as if commit `I` had changed.  But it hasn't: it's still right there, just as it was before.  We just can't *find* it, and that's what we want: commit `I` is no longer useful; `I'` is the new and improved `I`.

#### Branches and merges

Suppose we start out with a repository with a few commits, ending in `H`, and just one branch name `main`:

```
...--G--H   <-- main (HEAD)
```

We now create two *new* branch names, `br1` and `br2`, both also pointing to commit `H`:

```
...--G--H   <-- br1, br2, main (HEAD)
```

We switch to `br1` and create two new commits in the usual way:

```
          I--J   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- br2, main
```

Then we switch to `br2` and make two more commits:

```
          I--J   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          K--L   <-- br2 (HEAD)
```

We're now ready to use `git merge` to *merge* commits `J` and `L`.  Note that we don't merge *branches* in any real technical sense: we merge commits.  **The purpose of this merge is to combine work.**  We want the work we did "on" `br1`, *and* the work we did "on" `br2`.  We'll `git switch br1` and then `git merge br2` for instance.

We'll skip right ahead here to the mechanism, to save space in this answer:  The way Git achieves a merge is to *diff* (as in `git diff`) the *merge base* commit against each of the two branch tip commits, so that Git can figure out what *work was done*.  The obvious common starting point for the two branches is commit `H`.  It has a name (`main`) pointing to it, but that doesn't matter here, and in fact that name is kind of in the way so I'm going to stop drawing it in.  So Git runs, in effect:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-H> <hash-of-J>   # what we changed
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-H> <hash-of-L>   # what they changed
```

Git then *combines the diffs:* what we did to some file, we want to do again; what they did to some other file, we want to do again; if we both touched the *same* file, we want to make both changes.  We make these changes to the snapshot taken from commit `H`, which is the one on the left side of both `git diff` commands.

This produces a new snapshot, ready to be committed, or perhaps produces some merge conflicts that make Git stop and make us fix them up before the merge can be finished.  Assuming all goes well and Git does finish on its own, though, Git now makes a *merge commit*, which is nothing more than a commit with two parents:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   <-- br2
```

Note how merge commit `M` points backwards to *both* `J` *and* `L`.  As usual when making a new commit, Git has stuffed the new commit's hash ID into the current branch name—the one with `HEAD` attached—so now `br1` points to commit `M`.  It's now safe for us to *delete the name* `br2`, if we wish, as Git finds commits by walking *all* paths backwards, so when we select commit `M` with history, we get *all* the commits.

**This is the essence of a true merge.**  Git makes the *content* by combining work and applying the combined work to the *merge base*.  Git *finds* the merge base by working backwards from the two tip commits (along all paths!—but in our case it was easy as there was just the simple straight-line backwards path) until it finds some shared commit(s).  Technically, Git is using the [Lowest Common Ancestor algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_ancestor#Extension_to_directed_acyclic_graphs) here to find commit `H`, but for this case it's obvious by eyeball.

Having constructed the content, all on its own if possible, Git now makes the new snapshot and makes the metadata, with the *list of two parents* showing the then-current commit `J` first, and the other commit `L` second.  The order here usually doesn't matter, but when it does, `--first-parent` lets you direct Git to ignore all but the *first* parent.

#### Copying commits via `git cherry-pick`

Something that happens relatively often while working in Git is that we discover a bug that affects us on our feature branch, but also affects the more-main-ish branch we started from.  That is, perhaps we have this:

```
...--X--o--*--o--P   <-- main
            \
             F--G--H   <-- feature (HEAD)
```

We discover a bug now and realize that it was made back in commit `X`, so the bug is present on both `main` *and* `feature` branches.

There are a lot of strategies for fixing it (including some that don't involve cherry-pick), but it's pretty common for people to now fix the bug as an emergency on the `main` branch.  They add a new commit `C` that fixes the bug:

```
...--X--o--*--o--P--C   <-- main
            \
             F--G--H   <-- feature (HEAD)
```

We'd like the fix too, so we want to add a new commit that's a lot like `C`.  We could just duplicate their work and make a new commit `I`, but wouldn't it be nice if we could literally copy the *change* from `C`?  And we can:

```
git cherry-pick main
```

tells Git to look up commit `C` (as found by the name `main`), go back one hop to its parent `P`, diff the two snapshots to figure out what *changed*, and apply the same *change* to our commit `H` on *our* branch.

Technically, Git does this using the same merge code as for `git merge`, except that instead of the obvious merge base (commit `*`), it forces the merge base to be commit `P`, the parent of commit `C`, the commit we're copying.  The reason for this is that it produces the right answer (and if you think about it, or work through all the details, you'll see that it *does* produce the right answer), but for now we'll just think of it as "duplicate that work" and *assume* it works.  This gives us a new commit `C'`, which we call `C'` because it's so much like `C`.  Git even copies the *commit message* for us (though we can change it by adding `--edit`):

```
...--X--o--*--o--P--C   <-- main
            \
             F--G--H--C'  <-- feature (HEAD)
```

All we really need to remember here is that cherry-pick effectively copies a commit, to a new-and-improved commit.  The improvement in *this* case is that the new commit goes on our `feature` branch, and uses commit `H`'s snapshot as modified by whatever changed from `P` to `C`.

#### Simple rebase cases

We're now (finally!) ready to consider a simple `git rebase`.  Suppose we have finished our feature, including the cherry-pick:

```
...--X--o--*--o--P--C   <-- main
            \
             F--G--H--C'--I--J   <-- feature (HEAD)
```

We have but one regret, at this point: we wish we'd started our feature at commit `C`, so that we get all the goodies from the unnamed `o` after `*`, and `P`, and `C` itself.  So we run:

```
git rebase main
```

The argument here, `main`, selects commit `C` *with history*, so it means *every commit from `C` on backwards*.  That doesn't include any of our commits after commit `*`, because the arrows between commits all point *backwards*, and commit `F`, our first part of our feature, is *forwards* from `*`.

The commits selected here are temporarily "painted red", if you will: red means *stop, do not touch*.  Now Git starts adding some temporary green "paint" to our own commits, working backwards from the tip of `feature`.  This lists out the hash IDs for `J`, `I`, `C'`, `H`, `G`, and `F`.  Upon moving back from `*`, Git hits the "red paint" and stops moving back.

Git now cleans off all the temporary paint (this "paint" is really just some bits in some in-core data obtained by reading the commits from the objects database—it's just a way to mentally model how rebase works) and reverses the list of hash IDs, so that they're in the order Git will need when copying: `F`, `G`, ..., `J`.

There's now a special trick that rebase uses: it looks at the commits from `C` backwards to `*` too, to see if any of them "do the same thing" as any of the commits in the list above.  This *usually* manages to pick out `C` and `C'` as copies of each other.  Using this trick, Git *discards `C'` from our own list*.  The list now goes `F-G-H-I-J`.

Now, using the name `main` to select a commit *without* history, Git switches to that commit.  That's commit `C`, of course.  Git uses what Git calls *detached HEAD* mode for this operation, but if you prefer, you can think of this as using a temporary branch.  I'll just draw it with the literal detached HEAD here though:

```
...--X--o--*--o--P--C   <-- main, HEAD
            \
             F--G--H--C'--I--J   <-- feature
```

Git now begins using `cherry-pick`, one commit at a time.  First it copies `F` to a new-and-improved `F'`.  The improvement is that we start with the *snapshot* from `C`, and our new *parent*, when Git makes the new commit by cherry-picking, is `C`.  So our new commit goes on like this:

```
                      F'  <-- HEAD
                     /
...--X--o--*--o--P--C   <-- main
            \
             F--G--H--C'--I--J   <-- feature
```

Once `F'` exists, Git copies `G`, using `git cherry-pick` again.  This produces a new `G'`:

```
                      F'-G'  <-- HEAD
                     /
...--X--o--*--o--P--C   <-- main
            \
             F--G--H--C'--I--J   <-- feature
```

We repeat with every commit *except* `C'`, which got knocked out of the list:

```
                      F'-G'-H'-I'-J'  <-- HEAD
                     /
...--X--o--*--o--P--C   <-- main
            \
             F--G--H--C'--I--J   <-- feature
```

The copying phase is complete, so Git now forces the *name* `feature` to move to where we are now—commit `J'`—and then re-attaches `HEAD`, so that we're back in the normal working mode:

```
                      F'-G'-H'-I'-J'  <-- feature (HEAD)
                     /
...--X--o--*--o--P--C   <-- main
            \
             F--G--H--C'--I--J   [abandoned]
```

#### Interactive rebase

The interactive mode of `git rebase` turns each `git cherry-pick` operation into a separate `pick` command.  This allows you to shuffle the order of the commits around and/or to make some of them read `fixup` or `squash`, for instance.  On encountering one of the latter, Git effectively uses `git commit --amend` to make it look like Git combined two commits during the rebase.<sup>3</sup>

Besides this particular feature—of letting you rearrange and reorganize commits (and with a fair bit of extra work, even "split" a commit into two or more separate commits), this interactive rebase also offers the new `--rebase-merges` mode.  This does something fairly radical.

---

<sup>3</sup>This means that you get a lot of pointless temporary commits: `git fsck` will find them and tell you about the dangling commits, and that's perfectly normal.  They don't get `git push`-ed and your own Git will *eventually*, probably, delete them, after a suitable interval to make sure that you don't mind.  I'm not going to cover this for space reasons, but `git gc` is what cleans up here.  The newfangled `git maintenance` series of commands are meant to subsume `git gc` eventually.  Noteworthy: *GitHub* do not use `git gc`: "dangling" leftovers in a GitHub repository remain there forever, for internal implementation reasons, unless you get GitHub support to do it for you.

## [Part 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73466726/1256452)