# Git reset --soft BUT preserve Merge workflow

Tags: git, merge, version, reset

**Question:**

How do you preserve the branch merge workflow using git reset --soft

**Why:**

I'm trying to make some auto versioning Git actions. And the 1st implementation is making two (2) nodes indicating a pull request and an autoversioning.

[image: 2 Nodes used to update version after pull request]

I'm trying to use the following code in the git action to combine the changes

```
                 - name: Soft Reset to add changes to PR    
                   run: |
                     git config user.name github-actions
                     git config user.email github-actions@github.com
                     git reset --soft "HEAD~2"
                     git commit --amend --message="Version ${{ env.MYVERSION }}"
                     git push --force
```

What happens is that it properly combines the two (2) commits, but it breaks the diagonal line in the workflow signaling that the branches were merged.

[image]

I feel like I'm close, but I'm missing a key item.

2nd bonus question. How would I merge the two commits messages? 'cause I get the new message I force, but I would like the PR commit message too if possible.

Thank you for your time and consideration.

Comment: I believe that when you reset then make a new commit, git loses the track of the previous reseted commit, that's the why the diagonal line breaks. There is no longer a relationship between your version commit and the previous one.
If you want to keep the diagonal line you can't reset

Comment: That makes sense. I was hoping to be clever.... I appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 3):

> How do you preserve the branch merge workflow using git reset --soft

You don't.

A merge commit is a commit with two or more parents.

After `git switch name` followed by `git reset --soft hash-ID-or-other-commit-specifier`, you:

- are "on" branch *`name`* (still);
- the name *`name`* now selects the commit specified by the hash ID you gave in the `git reset` operation, instead of the previous tip commit;
- Git's *index* aka *staging area* contains the files from the old tip commit; and
- your working tree contains the same files as Git's index.

But running `git commit` now makes a new *ordinary*, i.e., single-parent, commit.

Running `git commit --amend` (as you're doing) makes a new commit whose parent(s) is/are the current commit's parent(s).  These are not the same parents as the original merge commit, since you've reset that one away.  To get the same parents, you wouldn't reset the merge away in the first place.

You *could* run `git commit-tree`—a low-level "plumbing" command—to make a new *merge commit*.  If you plan to do this, though, there's again no reason to use `git reset --soft` in the first place, as `git commit-tree` takes the following inputs:

- `-p` flag: supplies each parent hash ID (one `-p` flag per parent hash ID);
- `-F file` or `-m message`: supplies the commit message text;
- *`tree`*: supplies the Git hash ID of the tree you want as the saved snapshot.

The output from `git commit-tree` is a raw hash ID, which you must then shove into the branch name, the way `git commit` would; in general you do this with the `git update-ref` plumbing command.

If you need an updated tree object, you'd `git add` files to the index as usual and then use `git write-tree`—yet another plumbing command—to create the tree object first.

If your goal is to update a version file *in the merge*, rather than as a separate step after the merge, you again don't need a soft reset: instead, you'd check out the merge commit, update the version file, and do a `git commit --amend` while *on the merge commit* to make a new merge commit to replace the old merge commit.  Note, however, that the result is technically an [evil merge](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461909/1256452).

To avoid the evil merge, simply make the revision bump a separate commit, which requires no fanciness in the first place.

Comment: Thank you very much! I really appreciate you taking the time to explain everything. I will try to play w/ the ideas you presented, and like you said, I may just settle on two separate commits (which has it's advantages)